# How to get the current working directory in Java?

Tags: java, java-io

I want to access my current working directory using Java.

My code:

```
 String currentPath = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
 System.out.println("Current dir:" + currentPath);

 String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
 System.out.println("Current dir using System:" + currentDir);
```

Output:

```
Current dir: C:\WINDOWS\system32
Current dir using System: C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

My output is not correct because the C drive is not my current directory.

How to get the current directory?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish by accessing the working directory?  Could it be done by using the class path instead?  For example, if you need to read a text file on the file system, you can find it easily when it is on the class path.

Comment: how? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: For some information about accessing a file on the class path, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java

Comment: For debugging purposes, the working directory could be useful to know if the program doesn't seem to be able to access files that exist.

Comment: Both methods (and the methods below) look correct. If you get the system directory as CWD then this might be due to a wrapper doing a CD before starting Java. For example javapath might do this. Specify the path to java.exe to the actual Java_:home directory directly to avoid this.

Comment: Bear in mind that one thing is the working directory, and other the directory whether your class resides. They usually aren't the same.

Comment: @Qazi Did any of the below answers solve your case? Can you pick one of those as your answer?

Comment: Knowledge of the current working directory is important for all relative paths. If you think that is irrelevant make sure you always access files via some absolute path.
The classpath need not be the filesystem - it is entirely different.

Answer (score 1505):

**Code :**

```
public class JavaApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
  }
}
```

*This will print the absolute path of the current directory from where your application was initialized.*

---

**Explanation:**

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

`java.io` package resolve relative pathnames using current user directory. The current directory is represented as system property, that is, `user.dir` and is the directory from where the JVM was invoked.

Comment: @ubuntudroid: that's why i mentioned specifically that it will print the path from where the application had initialized.
My guess the thread starter directly run the jar/program after starting commnad prompt (which is basically at C:\WINDOWS\system32).
I hope you understand my point. 
Assuming you downvoted, appreciate that at least you cared to leave a response. :)

Comment: user.dir will get the path to the folder wherein the process was launched. To get the actual path to the application's main folder see my answer below.

Comment: The problem with the "user.dir" property is, as soon someone pass it as `-Duser.dir=...` or set it inside the code with `System.setProperty("user.dir", ...)` all code relying on it fails.

Comment: I mean "all code relying on it **to find the current directory** fails.". Not all code in general. (I was to slow to edit the original comment)

Comment: @SubOptimal if user setted -Duser.dir, propable he want to run this in custom working directory.

Comment: @barwnikk I full agree with you. In that case the user should not expect to get the directory from which `java` was called (must not the one where the `java` executable is sotred) by `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. What I meant all code which relies on that fact might not behave as expected.

Comment: @indyaah infact this answer is wrong, there is a subtle difference between a user-working-directory and a current-working-directory of a system process (cwd); most of time the "user.dir" points to the cwd of a (java)process; but "user.dir" has different semantics and shall not be used to obtain the cwd of a java process; btw:there are more properties available to java process https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html just for reference

Comment: I got `null` when using `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`

Comment: Downvote for not explaining enough how System.getProperty("user.dir") works.

Comment: try running this command with root user, you would find user.dir as "/"

Comment: This is more of a comment to the original question than an answer because the OP has already tried this option.

Comment: @indyaah what is this "subtle difference" between the user's working directory and current working directory?

Comment: Yes, current working directory is not the user's directory aka home. Nor is the current working directory where the executable lives. The current working directory is just that. It can be set in many cases explicitly when the process is started. And the application can change it as well.

Answer (score 548):

See: [Path Operations (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Classes > Basic I/O)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html).

Using `java.nio.file.Path` and `java.nio.file.Paths`, you can do the following to show what Java thinks is your current path. This for 7 and on, and uses NIO.

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
System.out.println("Current absolute path is: " + s);
```

This outputs:

```
Current absolute path is: /Users/george/NetBeansProjects/Tutorials
```

that in my case is where I ran the class from.

Constructing paths in a relative way, by not using a leading separator to indicate you are constructing an absolute path, will use this relative path as the starting point.

Comment: The first one haven' t checked, but the second one will actually get your home folder. Not the current working directory in which the application is running.

Comment: Please don't confuse the user's home directory ("user.home", /Users/george in your case) and the current working directory ("user.dir", which will be the directory from which you started the JVM for your application, so could be something like e.g. /Users/george/workspace/FooBarProject).

Comment: I prefer this way. When I need the parent of the working directory, this does *not* work: `Paths.get("").getParent()`, it gives `null`. Instead this works: `Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().getParent()`.

Comment: If you need to get the parent of the current directory just use the "..". example:
Paths.get("..").toAbsolutePath().normalize();

Comment: I've encountered (at least on Java 7) cases where `Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath()` was not returning the same value as `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. Thus they are not equivalent.
The scenario was debugging tests run using Maven without forking (`forkCount=0`): using  `Paths.get("")` was returning the root Maven module path (the directory in which the `mvn`command was started), while the  `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returned the current Maven module path. Quite unexpected and probably related to not forking.

Comment: Current working directory, user dir, home, application location are all different things. Often the current working directory is one of those, but it doesn't have to be. And the application can change it at any point.

Answer (score 262):

The following works on Java 7 and up (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) for documentation).

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
```

Comment: How is this better than the more portable `import java.io.File; File(".").getAbsolutePath()` ?

Comment: When you say portable, you mean it works in Java 6 and earlier? `Paths.get()` may be considered better in that it gives direct access to the more powerful `Path` interface.

Comment: What is the potential advantage of using `.normalize()` in this context?

Comment: @OleV.V. From Javadoc: (*normalize method*) `Returns a path that is this path with redundant name elements eliminated.`

Comment: What's the significance of `.` (dot)?
does it matter if we omit the dot?

Comment: The dot represents the current directory. `./test` is the file `test` in the current directory on *nix operating systems. On Windows it is `.\test`.

Answer (score 82):

This will give you the path of your current working directory:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".");
```

And this will give you the path to a file called "Foo.txt" in the working directory:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("Foo.txt");
```

**Edit :**
To obtain an absolute path of current directory:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".").toAbsolutePath();
```

*** Update ***
To get current working directory:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("").toAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: this just returns '.' for me.

Comment: Yes, in many systems that will be the reference to the working directory. To get the absolute path you can add one more method call `Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".").toAbsolutePath();`

Comment: You don't need the foo.txt, just put in an empty string to get the directory

Comment: On Windows (10) this just gives me a `Path` object pointing to a file called `.` inside the current working dir. Using an empty string, rather than `"."` worked for me.

Answer (score 82):

## Java 11 and newer

This solution is better than others and more portable:

```
Path cwd = Path.of("").toAbsolutePath();
```

Or even

```
String cwd = Path.of("").toAbsolutePath().toString();
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the answer from comeGetSome and is actually the Java <7 way

Comment: it should be Path cwd = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath();

Comment: Better to use `Path.of`, because [Paths might get deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html). Also, `Paths.get` just calls `Path.of`.

Comment: @onkarruikar good point, I’ll update the answer

Comment: Also prefer the dot rather than empty string as it is more understood in windows or posix system, it's the current directory. (Suggested in [Volodya Lombrozo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66786617/48136)).

Answer (score 38):

This is the solution for me

```
File currentDir = new File("");
```

Comment: This has side effects when you use such a File object as a parent of another File: new File(new File(""), "subdir") will not work as expected

Comment: To fix this, use `new File("").getAbsoluteFile()` instead.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had better luck with File(".").

Comment: [How To Define a Relative Path in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-a-relative-path-in-java) 
This Page helped me. Also I assumed that I should use `/` when creating a relative path. I was wrong, don't start with `/`. `../` also works for going up in the directory tree.

Comment: @keshlam That gave me a file in the current directory called `.`.

Answer (score 30):

What makes you think that *c:\windows\system32* is not your current directory? The [`user.dir`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) property is explicitly to be "User's current working directory".

To put it another way, unless you start Java from the command line, *c:\windows\system32* probably is your CWD. That is, if you are double-clicking to start your program, the CWD is unlikely to be the directory that you are double clicking from.

*Edit*: It appears that this is only true for old windows and/or Java versions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true, at least not on my Windows 7 machine using Java 7. `user.dir` is consistently the folder where I double-clicked the jar file.

Answer (score 26):

Use [`CodeSource#getLocation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html#getLocation--).

This works fine in JAR files as well. You can obtain `CodeSource` by [`ProtectionDomain#getCodeSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource--) and the `ProtectionDomain` in turn can be obtained by [`Class#getProtectionDomain()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getProtectionDomain--).

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        URL location = Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        System.out.println(location.getFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns the location of the JAR file. Not what was asked for.

Answer (score 24):

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()
```

Comment: Throws a NPE when I launch my application from a JAR file by double-clicking it.

Comment: This returns `""` if the application is running from a JAR file, or a CLASSPATH element. Not what was asked for.

Comment: @Zizouz212 `getClass()` is an object method, so in a static context just removing the `this` doesn't work. You'd have to explicitly refer to the class you're in by doing `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().....`.

Answer (score 19):

generally, as a File object:

```
File getCwd() {
  return new File("").getAbsoluteFile();
}
```

you may want to have full qualified string like "D:/a/b/c" doing:

```
getCwd().getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: This works well in Android tests since Android doesn't include java.nio.file.Files.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me in a static context (new File("") throws NullPointerException)..?

Comment: @nsandersen you probably used a wrong File object: System.out.println(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath());

Answer (score 15):

I'm on Linux and get same result for both of these approaches:

```
@Test
public void aaa()
{
    System.err.println(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString());

    System.err.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
}
```

[`Paths.get("")` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29)

[`System.getProperty("user.dir")` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score 7):

I hope you want to access the current directory including the package i.e. If your Java program is in `c:\myApp\com\foo\src\service\MyTest.java` and you want to print until `c:\myApp\com\foo\src\service` then you can try the following code:

```
String myCurrentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + File.separator
            + System.getProperty("sun.java.command")
                    .substring(0, System.getProperty("sun.java.command").lastIndexOf("."))
                    .replace(".", File.separator);
    System.out.println(myCurrentDir);
```

***Note:*** This code is only tested in Windows with Oracle JRE.

Comment: It would be disservice not to downvote this answer. Please think more carefully before posting. Your code is broken, unless all these are true: 1. the JRE is Oracle's, otherwise there will be no "sun.java.command" system property → NPE; 2. the OS is Windows (Use `File.separator` instead, or a multi-argument `File` constructor); 3. the classpath is specificed on the command line, _and_ the 'current directory including the package'(??) is: a. specified first, b. specified absolutely, c. matches the CWD exactly (even with Windows' case insensitivity), and d. is a descendent of the CWD

Comment: That addresses points 1 and 2. But unless I'm missing something, you're still relying on the classpath being specified in the command line (i.e. not in an environment variable), and for the 'current directory including the package' (I admit I don't really understand what you mean by that) being a descendent of specifically the first element in the classpath. And the case matching problem remains.

I'm sorry if my comment wasn't helpful; I sacrificed clarity to keep within the comment character limit.

Comment: @Inversus, it only "works perfectly" in some environments; you just happened to be lucky enough to test it in onesuch. Writing software that fails in legitimate runtime environments is not good practice, even when your set of test environments isn't expansive enough to include them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right, that is not good practice. Fortunately, this solution "solv[ing] my specific issue" did not cause it to "[fail] in legitimate runtime environments." In fact, it helped me solve such a failure and write more robust code, besides solving the very specific issue I had (which was only somewhat related to this question/answer). I guess I was just lucky to find it.

Answer (score 5):

On **Linux** when you run a **jar** file from **terminal**, these both will return the same `String`: ***"/home/CurrentUser"***, no matter, where youre jar file is. It depends just on what current directory are you using with your terminal, when you start the jar file.

```
Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();

System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

If your `Class` with `main` would be called `MainClass`, then try:

```
MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile();
```

This will return a `String` with **absolute path** of the **jar** file.

Comment: Which is not what was asked for.

Comment: This answer is not to be taken literally.

Answer (score 5):

Using Windows user.dir returns the directory as expected, but NOT when you start your application with elevated rights (run as admin), in that case you get C:\WINDOWS\system32

Answer (score 4):

**Mention that it is checked only in `Windows` but i think it works perfect on other Operating Systems [`Linux,MacOs,Solaris`] :).**

---

I had **2** `.jar` files in the same directory . I wanted from the one `.jar` file to start the other `.jar` file which is in the same directory.

The problem is that when you start it from the `cmd` the current directory is `system32`.

---

> Warnings!

- The below seems to work pretty well in all the test i have done even
  with folder name `;][[;'57f2g34g87-8+9-09!2#@!$%^^&()` or `()%&$%^@#`
  it works well.
- I am using the `ProcessBuilder` with the below as following:

..

```
//The class from which i called this was the class `Main`
String path = getBasePathForClass(Main.class);
String applicationPath=  new File(path + "application.jar").getAbsolutePath();


System.out.println("Directory Path is : "+applicationPath);

//Your know try catch here
//Mention that sometimes it doesn't work for example with folder `;][[;'57f2g34g87-8+9-09!2#@!$%^^&()` 
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", applicationPath);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();

//...code
```

---

`getBasePathForClass(Class<?> classs)`:

```
    /**
     * Returns the absolute path of the current directory in which the given
     * class
     * file is.
     * 
     * @param classs
     * @return The absolute path of the current directory in which the class
     *         file is.
     * @author GOXR3PLUS[StackOverFlow user] + bachden [StackOverFlow user]
     */
    public static final String getBasePathForClass(Class<?> classs) {

        // Local variables
        File file;
        String basePath = "";
        boolean failed = false;

        // Let's give a first try
        try {
            file = new File(classs.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());

            if (file.isFile() || file.getPath().endsWith(".jar") || file.getPath().endsWith(".zip")) {
                basePath = file.getParent();
            } else {
                basePath = file.getPath();
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            failed = true;
            Logger.getLogger(classs.getName()).log(Level.WARNING,
                    "Cannot firgue out base path for class with way (1): ", ex);
        }

        // The above failed?
        if (failed) {
            try {
                file = new File(classs.getClassLoader().getResource("").toURI().getPath());
                basePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

                // the below is for testing purposes...
                // starts with File.separator?
                // String l = local.replaceFirst("[" + File.separator +
                // "/\\\\]", "")
            } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(classs.getName()).log(Level.WARNING,
                        "Cannot firgue out base path for class with way (2): ", ex);
            }
        }

        // fix to run inside eclipse
        if (basePath.endsWith(File.separator + "lib") || basePath.endsWith(File.separator + "bin")
                || basePath.endsWith("bin" + File.separator) || basePath.endsWith("lib" + File.separator)) {
            basePath = basePath.substring(0, basePath.length() - 4);
        }
        // fix to run inside netbeans
        if (basePath.endsWith(File.separator + "build" + File.separator + "classes")) {
            basePath = basePath.substring(0, basePath.length() - 14);
        }
        // end fix
        if (!basePath.endsWith(File.separator)) {
            basePath = basePath + File.separator;
        }
        return basePath;
    }
```

Comment: This returns the location of the JAR file. Not what was asked for.

Comment: @EJP The location of the .jar file isn't the current working directory of the java program?

Answer (score 2):

assume that you're trying to run your project inside eclipse, or netbean or stand alone from command line. I have write a method to fix it

```
public static final String getBasePathForClass(Class<?> clazz) {
    File file;
    try {
        String basePath = null;
        file = new File(clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        if (file.isFile() || file.getPath().endsWith(".jar") || file.getPath().endsWith(".zip")) {
            basePath = file.getParent();
        } else {
            basePath = file.getPath();
        }
        // fix to run inside eclipse
        if (basePath.endsWith(File.separator + "lib") || basePath.endsWith(File.separator + "bin")
                || basePath.endsWith("bin" + File.separator) || basePath.endsWith("lib" + File.separator)) {
            basePath = basePath.substring(0, basePath.length() - 4);
        }
        // fix to run inside netbean
        if (basePath.endsWith(File.separator + "build" + File.separator + "classes")) {
            basePath = basePath.substring(0, basePath.length() - 14);
        }
        // end fix
        if (!basePath.endsWith(File.separator)) {
            basePath = basePath + File.separator;
        }
        return basePath;
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot firgue out base path for class: " + clazz.getName());
    }
}
```

To use, everywhere you want to get base path to read file, you can pass your anchor class to above method, result may be the thing you need :D

Best,

Comment: This returns the location of the JAR file. Not what was asked for.

Comment: @user207421 yes I know this answer is not the true answer for the question, but most of time, everybody want to get the "directory where the jars located" instead of "command line working directory".

Answer (score 2):

For Java 11 you could also use:

```
var path = Path.of(".").toRealPath();
```

Answer (score 1):

Current working directory is defined differently in different Java implementations. For certain version prior to Java 7 there was no consistent way to get the working directory. You could work around this by launching Java file with `-D` and defining a variable to hold the info

Something like

```
java -D com.mycompany.workingDir="%0"
```

That's not quite right, but you get the idea. Then `System.getProperty("com.mycompany.workingDir")`...

Comment: Not relevant to the question.

Comment: It does have a meaning to Java - it's the location on disk where files that you open with relative pathnames are relative to.

Comment: Yes, it has a meaning. My words were somewhat poorly chosen. But you miss the point - prior to Java 7 there was no way to know the current working directory, and different implementations set them...differently...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very confuse topic, and we need to understand some concepts before providing a real solution.

1. The File, and NIO File Api approaches with relative paths `""` or `"."` uses internally the system parameter `"user.dir"` value to determine the return location.
2. The `"user.dir`" value is based on the USER working directory, and the behavior of that value depends on the operative system, and the way the jar is executed.
3. For example, executing a JAR from Linux using a File Explorer (opening it by double click) will set `user.dir` with the user home directory, regardless of the location of the jar. If the same jar is executed from command line, it will return the jar location, because each `cd` command to the jar location modified the working directory.

Having said that, the solutions using `Java NIO`, `Files` or `"user.dir"` property will work for all the scenarios in the way the `"user.dir"` has the correct value.

```java
String userDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String userDirectory2 = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
String userDirectory3 = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();
```

We could use the following code:

```java
new File(MyApp.class.getProtectionDomain()
                     .getCodeSource()
                     .getLocation()
                     .toURI().getPath())
     .getParent();
```

to get the current location of the executed JAR, and personally I used the following approach to get the expected location and overriding the `"user.dir"` system property at the very beginning of the application. So, later when the other approaches are used, I will get the expected values always.

More details here -> https://blog.adamgamboa.dev/getting-current-directory-path-in-java/

```java
    public class MyApp {
      
      static {
        //This static block runs at the very begin of the APP, even before the main method.
        try{
          File file = new File(MyApp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
                           .getLocation().toURI().getPath());
          String basePath = file.getParent();
          //Overrides the existing value of "user.dir"
          System.getProperties().put("user.dir", basePath);
        }catch(URISyntaxException ex){
          //log the error
        }
      }
     
      public static void main(String args []){
        //Your app logic
        
        //All these approaches should return the expected value
        //regardless of the way the jar is executed.
        String userDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String userDirectory2 = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        String userDirectory3 = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();
      }
    }
```

I hope this explanation and details are helpful to others...

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish but the above answers work on the current working directory where you are asking from not from where the program is actually located.

For instance:

```
$> mkdir -p /tmp/paths/check 
$> cat > /tmp/paths/check/GetPath.java
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;

public class GetPath {
// Note: these methods work slightly differently, the last two will provide the working dir
// for where this program was launched, while the first will get the cwd from where this
// program resides.
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rootPath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
        System.out.println("Thread rootPath is "+rootPath);
        System.out.println("System property user.dir is "+System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.out.println("NIO Paths way is "+Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("NIO FileSystems way is "+FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("").toAbsolutePath());
}
}
```

Then if you run it from /tmp, you will see:

```
$> cd /tmp/paths/check; javac GetPath.java
$> cd /tmp
$> java -cp paths/check GetPath
Thread rootPath is /tmp/paths/check/
system property user.dir is /tmp
NIO Paths way is/tmp
NIO FileSystems way is/tmp
```

So the first method using the `ContextClassLoader` may be more appropriate depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This is my silver bullet when ever the moment of confusion bubbles in.(Call it as first thing in main). Maybe for example JVM is slipped to be different version by IDE. This static function searches current process PID and opens VisualVM on that pid. Confusion stops right there because you  want it all and you get it...

```
  public static void callJVisualVM() {
    System.out.println("USER:DIR!:" + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    //next search current jdk/jre
    String jre_root = null;
    String start = "vir";
    try {
        java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean runtime =
                java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        String jvmName = runtime.getName();
        System.out.println("JVM Name = " + jvmName);
        long pid = Long.valueOf(jvmName.split("@")[0]);
        System.out.println("JVM PID  = " + pid);
        Runtime thisRun = Runtime.getRuntime();
        jre_root = System.getProperty("java.home");
        System.out.println("jre_root:" + jre_root);
        start = jre_root.concat("\\..\\bin\\jvisualvm.exe " + "--openpid " + pid);
        thisRun.exec(start);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.getProperties().list(System.out);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should write a book about this question. These 50 lines of code are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what's asked, but here's an important note: When running Java on a Windows machine, the Oracle installer puts a "java.exe" into C:\Windows\system32, and this is what acts as the launcher for the Java application (UNLESS there's a java.exe earlier in the PATH, and the Java app is run from the command-line). This is why File(".") keeps returning C:\Windows\system32, *and* why running examples from macOS or *nix implementations keep coming back with different results from Windows.

Unfortunately, there's really no universally correct answer to this one, as far as I have found in twenty years of Java coding unless you want to create your own native launcher executable using JNI Invocation, and get the current working directory from the native launcher code when it's launched. Everything else is going to have at least some nuance that could break under certain situations.

Comment: This was true long ago (when this Q was posted), but Microsoft discouraged apps changing system32, and since at least 2015 the Oracle Windows installers put their stub in either `\programdata\Oracle\Java\javapath` or `\Program Files [(x86)]\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`as approved by MS

Comment: Noticed that myself recently--good update! I think older installers (Java 1.8) will still do the original behavior, but definitely the behavior you cite is one I'm seeing from the more recent builds/installs. (Personally I dislike a global Java anywhere, but that's me.)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this I know I am late for the answer but this obvious thing happened in java8 a new version from where this question is asked but..

The code

```
import java.io.File;

public class Find_this_dir {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//some sort of a bug in java path is correct but file dose not exist
        File this_dir = new File("");

//but these both commands work too to get current dir        
//      File this_dir_2 = new File(this_dir.getAbsolutePath());
        File this_dir_2 = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath());

        System.out.println("new File(" + "\"\"" + ")");
        System.out.println(this_dir.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(this_dir.exists());
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("new File(" + "new File(" + "\"\"" + ").getAbsolutePath()" + ")");
        System.out.println(this_dir_2.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(this_dir_2.exists());
    }
}
```

This will work and show you the current path but I don't now why java fails to find current dir in ***`new File("");`*** besides I am using Java8 compiler...

This works just fine I even tested it `new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath());`

Now you have current directory in a File object so (Example file object is f then),

`f.getAbsolutePath()` will give you the path in a String varaible type...

Tested in another directory that is not drive C works fine

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method is to get it from the system environment variables attached to the current running process. In this case, your application is being managed by the JVM.

```
String currentDir = System.getenv("PWD");
/*
 /home/$User/Documents/java
*/
```

To view other environment variables that you might find useful like, home dir, os version ........

```
//Home directory
String HomeDir = System.getEnv("HOME");


//Outputs for unix
/home/$USER

//Device user
String user = System.getEnv("USERNAME");


//Outputs for unix
$USER
```

The beautiful thing with this approach is that all paths will be resolved for all types of OS platform

Comment: Does it work on Windows?

Comment: Yes ofcourse it should work on windows. Though it will give you windows resolved path format.. something like `c//user//`

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I'm a mac user but currently working on a compose multiplatform app and It should also work on windows

Answer (score 0):

You might use `new File("./")`. This way `isDirectory()` returns true (at least on Windows platform). On the other hand `new File("") isDirectory()` returns false.

Answer (score -1):

None of the answers posted here worked for me.  Here is what did work:

```
java.nio.file.Paths.get(
  getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()
);
```

Edit:  The final version in my code:

```
URL myURL = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
java.net.URI myURI = null;
try {
    myURI = myURL.toURI();
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) 
{}
return java.nio.file.Paths.get(myURI).toFile().toString()
```

Comment: This returns the location of the JAR file. Not what was asked for.

Answer (score -6):

`System.getProperty("java.class.path")`