# Location for rcp eclipse application

Tags: eclipse, location, rcp

How do i get the location where an rcp eclipse exported application is running ?

thank you

Comment: Is this what you're after: [Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)?

Comment: Your question is not well formulated. For what do you need that location? Maybe there is an other way to resolve your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at the class `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform`. More specifically the method `getInstallLocation()`. There are more methods of the form `getXYZLocation()` that might be more appropriate depending on what you need. Just display the locations in e.g. a message dialog to see where they point if the Javadoc isn't clear enough.