# How to get the directory of the CMD when I execute a java executable file (.exe)

Tags: java

How would you find the current directory which the CMD is currently in from a java file which has been exported and converted into a .exe file.

I'm not looking for the current working directory as that only gets me the location of the .exe file.

`System.getProperty("user.dir")`  is not what I'm looking for.
Same with   new File(".")

If the cmd is `C:Users/User/Desktop`  and I then call `file.exe`, I would like to know the path   `C:Users/User/Desktop`, not the directory of the `file.exe`.

I convert the Main.java file to an .exe by:   (Using Eclipse)
  Export as a Runnable Jar File a  s file.jar

Launch4j - Outputfile = file.exe - Jar runtime path = Jars/file.jar - Don't wrap jar, launch only

Comment: Those answers only get me the location of the executable file, not the location of the cmd from where it was executed.

Comment: File f = new File("");
  System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: It still only gets me the directory from where the executable file is, not where it is executed from by the cmd.

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22350931/1410303)

Comment: Same result as the other 2.

Comment: I think converting to .exe file might be the reason for your troubles, as it might be that it changes the current directory and that is the reason you'd get surprising results. If you use a java .jar and not an exe file, does getting the cmd directory then work as expected?

Comment: @Sam Please edit your question to include the detailed description of how you create the `.exe` file. Also include the source code you have and the output you get, called from various locations in your file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787150/get-current-directory-from-the-command-prompt-when-calling-a-java-application) You would use:

```java
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

It will give you the users working directory.

Output is:

```
C:\Foo> java -jar bar\baz.jar
Directory: C:\Foo
```

Because this isn't working for you the problem must come from Launch4J.

When you're starting Launch4j there is a little dot at the Option Basic -> Change Dir, remove it and you'll be happy.

[image: Change Dir Option]

For Reference here is my Launch4J Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>console</headerType>
  <jar>C:\Foo\bar\baz.jar</jar>
  <outfile>C:\Foo\bar\baz.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir></chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <jre>
    <path></path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion>1.6</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Another possible workaround would be to use a `.bat` file like:

```
java -jar bar\baz.jar
```

And wrap this bat into an exe file.

Comment: Again, this gives the directory of the executable file, not the directory of the cmd when the file is executed.

Comment: @Sam Maybe your *.exe is part of your problem. You might try that with a jar file. If you need to have an exe, don't wrap the jar inside the exe, just use the exe as a launcher (I think Launch4j has an option for that) and your problem might be solved.

Comment: Ok, will try that, thx

Comment: I converting it without wrapping, but I still get the directory of the .exe file, not the directory which the cmd is currently in, when I execute the .exe file

Comment: Try to call the jar rather than the exe, so we can narrow down the error.

Comment: @Campingenieur when I call the file.jar, I'd doesn't output anything.                          I've exported the .java file as a .jar file                                                                          And the .java file is                                                                                                         String path = System.getProperty("user.dir"); System.out.println(path);

Comment: @Sam Well that is strange I've build a jar file only with ```System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))``` in main too and when I call the jar from directory ```foo``` via ```java -jar bar/Test.jar``` the output is ```foo```. So this must be an issue from launch4j.

Comment: @VinayHegde Your solution uses the exact same approach, so it would work too.

Comment: Idk, I'll figure it out another time

Comment: @Sam Take a look at my edit, I've found a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197963/discussion-between-campingenieur-and-sam).

Comment: Removing the chdir option worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class GetExePath
{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try{
      String exePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
      System.out.print("exe path at ="+exePath .replace("\\", "/"));
    }catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Some Exception ="+e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Output :

```
D:\vinay_hegde\javaexample>javac GetExePath.jav

D:\vinay_hegde\javaexample>java GetExePath
exe path at = D:\vinay_hegde\javaexample
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is giving me the directory of the executable file, not the directory of the cmd from where the file was executed from.

Comment: hmm, different to what I'm getting. Maybe its the way I'm creating the .exe file