# Java FileReader not finding files

Tags: java, filereader

I decided to start a new question so it can strictly focus on the FileReader errors.

This is a method that takes in a file name, and a desired output name for a new file. Say the inputted filename is "hello.txt"... the method makes it something like "/home/User/hello.txt", which goes into the FileReader as a parameter. The problem is that I get this as output "/home/User/hello.txt (No such file or directory)", even though the file does exist and the directory structure and permissions are correct.

I couldn't get the method to work with just referencing the file in the local directory of the .class and .java file so I googled my way to find that absolute specifying is not a bad option.

Any input is helpful!

```
public void fileGenerator(String in, String out) {      
try {
    String current_directory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(current_directory+"/"+in));
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(current_directory+"/"+out);
        while(input.hasNext()) {
        String line = input.nextLine(); 
    output.println(line);
    output.close(); 
    }
  }  catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }
}
```

Here is the requested stacktrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/User/hello.txt

(No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at TEST.fileGenerator(TEST.java:131)
    at TEST.generateCSV_TWO(TEST.java:122)
    at TEST$4.actionPerformed(TEST.java:102)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:253)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6203)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5968)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4564)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4390)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4461)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4125)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4055)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2149)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4390)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:649)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:622)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:620)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:619)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Print out what `current_directory` is and confirm that it matches your expectations.

I'd also print out the complete file path that you pass to the `FileReader` as well.

Most times that behavior doesn't match my expectations, I find that my assumptions were wrong.

Comment: Believe the JVM.  If it says it does not exist, then there's something else going on.

Comment: I just tested the code in a simplified java file and it worked so you may be right.

Answer (score 0):

No such file or directory would normally mean file does not exist. Please edit the code and debug it either using a IDE or by adding print statements. Also, current_directory could be renamed currentDirectory to be consistent with [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Try running code below.

```
public static void fileGenerator(String in, String out) {      
try {
    String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println(currentDirectory);
    String inputFileName = currentDirectory+"/"+in;
    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
    System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    FileReader inputFileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFileReader);
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(currentDirectory+"/"+out);
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        String line = input.nextLine(); 
    output.println(line);
    output.close(); 
    }
  }  catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: It matches the printed out directory perfectly. Sorry for the naming conventions, I'm a PHP dev just dabbling with Java

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. Did it print out the file's absolute path?