# FileNotFoundException when trying to create a FileReader in Java

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

```
import java.io.*;

public class Roi {

    public static void main( String[] args) {
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader("input.csv");

    }
}
```

I have the above code where I am trying to create a FileReader for a csv file, but I keep getting a FileNotFoundException.  I've just installed Eclipse, so I don't have any special paths set up or anything, but shouldn't this work if I keep the input file in the project directory?

I've tried putting the input file in the project directory, the project\src directory, and project\bin directory, but none seem to work.

Comment: put the file in `project` folder itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392435/java-filereader-not-finding-files

Comment: Do `System.out.println(new File("input.csv").getAbsolutePath());` to see where the system is looking.

Answer (score 2):

Put the file in folder /project

Answer (score 1):

If you go into menu Run -> Run Configurations then select the Arguments tab, you will find a setting near the bottom for what directory to run from.  Set this to wherever input.csv is.

(UI description assumes Eclipse Juno, but should be similar for older versions)