# How to obtain a name of a current folder?

Tags: java

The thing is that `System.getProperty("user.dir");` obtains a path *without* a current folder. So if class is stored in `C:\Users\Nika\workspace\sint\src` the output is `C:\Users\Nika\workspace\sint`. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by _current folder_? The name of the directory in which the JVM is executing? If so `new File(".").getName()`.

Comment: See Java File class - it is all there

Comment: I think you'll have to clarify what you want.

Comment: Look. If the JAR file's full name is `D:\Projects\Compiled\Other\MyJar.jar`, I want program to output `D:\Projects\Compiled\Other\MyJar.jar`. Just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findResource%28java.lang.String%29)

```
URL url = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource(Test.class.getName().concat(".class"));
System.out.println(url.getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you if you want the current working directory:

[Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The source directory for a `.java` is not stored anywhere.  You can obtain the based directory of the location of the `.class` file by getting the protection domain, however this is usally not needed.

Perhaps what you are trying to do is get a file using the class path. In this case I would suggest using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsInputStream()`

Answer (score 0):

Because class loader has current path to it. If yoy create jar then src path would not be valid. so append package name if classes are not in archive