# Delete a file across multiple operating systems

Tags: java, linux, cron, cross-compiling

So I have a program that runs something like the following

```
public class SHandler extends Handler { 
    File lmpFile;
```

Down later in the program:

```
lmpFile = new File("Stuff.zip"); // This should create a file called "stuff.zip" in the present directory
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(lmpFile); // Fill the file with whatever
```

Then from my main I call

```
 S.SHandler SpecialSH = new S.SHandler(args);
 //use the object for whatever
 SpecialSH.delFile();
```

Delfile is made like this and is a method inside the class:

```
public void delFile() {
    lmpFile.deleteOnExit();
    lmpXMLFile.deleteOnExit();
}
```

To my knowledge this program works right on my local machine (Windows 7 Enterprise), however on our development box when I run this it's tossing a LOT of files that the program pulls all over the place.  The execution path is /usr/data/dev/Handler and it's putting "stuff.zip" (and the files extracted from it) in /etc/cron.d and despite trying to remove them I am unable to.

*Note* This program is being called via a bash script which is invoked by a cron job on a machine running RHEL6.   Anyone able to help this would get my undying love and appreciation.

Edit:  The bash script is simply:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/data/java/current
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

/usr/data/java/current/bin/java -jar /usr/data/dev/Handler/Handler.jar
```

Tl;DR: File runs fine on windows, when RHEL6 calls a cron, files end up where they shouldn't.  How can I make my program handle this?

Comment: So, is the problem that files are created in an unexpected place, or that they aren't being deleted when the program exits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java) is `/etc/cron.d/` (executable path is different).

Relative paths (when using [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29)), are relative to the working directory. If you want your files placed in a different directory, use absolute file paths: `/path/to/stuff.zip` (note the leading slash).

Comment: You could also add `cd desired-directory` to the bash script, just before the call to the Java program.

Comment: Or set an environment variable on each system and retrieve it in the Java code and append to the file name as the path.

Comment: @Damien.Bell, is there a reason you're not using `File.Delete()`?

Comment: I can use file.delete, but there's times where it calls before I wanted it to, deleteonexit() ensures that when the program closes it's done.

Comment: @Damien.Bell Does changing directories result in the files being deleted afterwards?

Comment: I'll follow this up with an answer in just a moment if it does, I'm changing the cron now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these files are not closed, when delete occurs, or perhaps, an other program use them ?