# how to read file.properties

Tags: java, properties

I have a project organized this:

```
-LIBRERIA CLIENT/
   -SRC/
     -CONNECTION/
      CONNECTIONdB.JAVA
      CONFIG.PROPERTIES
```

In `CONNECETIONDB` I have this code to read the `CONFIG.PROPERTIES` file:

```
public static void connect() throws RemoteException
{
        //read file config.properties:
        String dbHost="",dbUser="",dbPassword="";
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        try
        {
            //load il file:
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/Connectionconfig.properties"));
            //read the property of file
            dbHost=prop.getProperty("host");
            dbUser=prop.getProperty("user");
            dbPassword=prop.getProperty("password");
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fe){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Error reading configuration file");
        }
```

But I have this error:

```
     FILE NOT FOUND
```

Could someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: No need to SHOUT. All caps is considered SHOUTING and rude.

Comment: Extensive usage of caps-lock won't help you...

Comment: What do you think "File not found" means?

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING? If the file wasn't found, it means the file was not where you tried to load it from.

Comment: If the application reads in a Webapplication context this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream

Answer (score 1):

That's easy: your code is executed in different folders from your project_root. Moreover: `src/Connectionconfig.properties` does not exists: it should be `SRC/CONNECTION/CONFIG.PROPERTIES`, if you execute project from project_root.
Also look at this to get current working directory: [Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your code read `Connectionconfig.properties` file under `src` but according to your project structure only `CONFIG.PROPERTIES` exists under `SRC/CONNECTION`.
Change to

```
  prop.load(new FileInputStream("SRC/CONNECTION/CONFIG.PROPERTIES"));
```

instead of

```
  prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/Connectionconfig.properties"));
```