# Relative path, how exactly work?

Tags: java, path, nio, relative-path

I have the following code:

```
//on WINDOWS:
Path path = Paths.get("photos\\vacation"); // windows
Path path1 = Paths.get("yellowstone");
Path path2 = path.relativize(path1);
System.out.print(path2);
```

**output:** ../yellowstone

```
//on LINUX
Path path = Paths.get("photos/vacation"); // unix
Path path1 = Paths.get("yellowstone");
Path path2 = path.relativize(path1);
System.out.print(path2);
```

**output:** ../../yellowstone

Why do I get two different relative paths? 
The official [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize%28java.nio.file.Path%29) mentions only that if both paths have a root component (which is not the case) the result will be system dependent.

Is there a different rule for windows? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the value of `File.separatorChar` as a sanity check?

Comment: @chrylis I am using linux hence is /. However as long as it's an abstract path it should be supporting both for managing abstract paths.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik just preparing for the OCPJP7 and if in the exam they use Windows.. it might be a different answer as you can see from the output I posted.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik No I do not have windows, but I know it's possible to use \\ in a relative path on Windows from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-relative-path-in-java

Comment: I do not want to use \\ instead of /.. it's just for ruling out a possible exam question with \\ instead of /

Comment: Looking at the relativized path is seems the Windows version has interpreted "photos\\vacation" as a single path element (not as two parts).  I don't see anything in the Javadoc stating how path elements (that are multi-part) are split; though it strongly implies that they are: re java.nio.file.Paths.get():  "Converts a path string, or a sequence of strings that when joined form a path string, to a Path. If more does not specify any elements then the value of the first parameter is the *path* string to convert."  (My emphasis.)

Comment: The safe way to create this path seems to be: 'Path path = Paths.get("photos", "vacation");', if that is any help.

Comment: @Paul I have tried that code the "windows" bit on a Ubuntu platform. I do not have a copy of Windows os so I cannot try it.