# How do I get the relative path of files in my project?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating a project using **jsp/servlet** in which I am trying to create java file and class file inside the project itself. But I am able to do this for only my system because the path I give their is like : **C:\Users\MySystem\Desktop\Test\..** which works only for my system. What should I do so that if I have to run this project in another system I don't have to change path again and again.

Comment: may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-relative-path-in-java

Comment: I think its something different or maybe I did not get it.

Comment: I hate seeing "please halp!11" in a question. You should definitely read this: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: In a `HttpServlet` you can use `this.getServletContext().getRealPath("")` to get the root directory of the deployed servlet. Not sure if it works for jsp, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if it is maven project just put your resources files under `src/main/resources`
and you can read them using this lines.

```
String path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                    .getResource("yourFileName").getPath();
System.out.println(path);
```

Or even this way you can do it.

```
String pathOfTheFile = getServletContext().getResource("yourFile").getPath();
```

and don't forget to put the file under `web-content` or `webapp` folder