# How can I get the filepath where my project is stored from inside the project?

Tags: java

I'm working on a project for school that needs to read from text files inside the project directory. I have it working but only because I have the filepath hardcoded to my computer.

i.e.

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\MyName\\workspace\\ProjectName\\"
```

If I sent it to my teacher, the filepath would result in an error.

Is there a way I can set the filepath to wherever the project is stored, from inside the project?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/264434/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/difference-absolute-path-relative-paths - that should help you

Comment: String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

Comment: FYI slash works just fine, Java will convert to Windows' backspash `C:/Users/...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the file name.

String path = "XPTO.txt"

This means your file is in the project root.

Comment: Will this also work if my file is in a subdirectory instead of the project root, and then adding the subdirectory in front of it?

Comment: Yes works too. Do not forget to make the scape for "/".

Answer (score 1):

Resource files can be place relative to the class files in your project (in this manner, they can be packaged together with class files as a jar file). To access these from within your project, you can use Class.getResource() or Class.getResourceAsStream. For instance...

```
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream('path/to/file');
```

Where 'path/to/file' is the path relative to where MyClass resides. Note the lack of a '/' at the beginning of this path - if it began with '/' it would be an absolute path relative to the highest package level of the project. Also note that one can use a relative file path to read a file external to the class package directory structure.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean when you say 'path/to/file'. If I put the project's filepath there, would the filepath not change when I send it to my teacher? And then I would have the same problem.

Comment: @yourselvs read the link I commented on your question to see the difference between relative (related to where your project is) and absolute (related to the root of the file system - "C:\" in your case) file paths.

Comment: You are reading the file RELATIVE to where the class is (as opposed to absolute as your initial post is suggesting you are doing). See the link @soong provided.

Answer (score 0):

Just do WhateverNeedsAPath("Something") //path will be whereever/ProjectName/Something

This might help you also: [How to define a relative path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-relative-path-in-java)