# Can't find the file in Java web project

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, web

I was stuck here for last all night. 
In my project, I need to read the xml file and use the relative path.(like String location = "AuctionItem.xml"; File f = new File(location);  below)

```
String location = "AuctionItem.xml";
File f = new File(location);
Document doc = builder.parse(f);
```

It worked well if I used a java text file.

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    File f = new File("AuctionItem.xml");
    System.out.println(AuctionItemsControl.getValue().size());
// here the method below is call the function which has the relative path.
}
```

However, when I used them in my project by jsp, it gave a error :
java.io.FileNotFoundException:/Users/XXX/Documents/Tool/web/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/AuctionItem.xml (No such file or directory)

Comment: does the file really exist in directory `/Users/XXX/Documents/Tool/web/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS`?

Comment: no, I use the relative path and the file exists in the project which is :

/Users/XXX/Dropbox/Mu/Study/UNSW/Semester4/comp9321/workplace/Assignment01/AuctionItem.xml

Comment: then change your location as `String location = "//Users//XXX//Dropbox/Mu//Study//UNSW//Semester4//comp9321//workplace//Assignment01//Aucti‌​onItem.xml"`

Comment: Yes, I tried that and worked. 
But I need to use relative path here. It's a homework.

Comment: define your [relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-a-relative-path-in-java) . If you didnt specify the path, it will point to project directory by default