# Playing a file from within the project map

Tags: java, netbeans

I am making an little Java music player application in netbeans(not for android). we have made an asset folder within the project with the sings in it the music player should play. we have all functions working, exept we can't figure out how to call up the song from within the project map. we now have hardcoded it in on a specific location, but that wont work on a different computer.

Does someone have a solution so that we can call up the song from within our project map?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understood what you mean, but what about a properties file which could be defined by the user? You could set up the path to the songs in that properties file and load it from the application.

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-a-relative-path-in-java). If I understand correctly, you just want a relative path to the music.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have an `Assets` folder in your project, you could do something like this:

```
initializeAudio("Assets/my_cool_song.wav");
```

where `initializeAudio` relies on a class-level declaration of a `Clip` object:

```
private void initializeAudio(final File url) {
    try {
        if (clip != null) stopPlay();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(inputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        stopPlay();
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The reason that this works on all computers with the project (or JAR), and `initializeAudio("/Users/myusername/Developer/Projects/AudioApp/Assets/my_cool_song.wave");` doesn't work is because one relies on a hard-coded absolute path, and the other relies on a file-path relative to the structure of the project. When creating relative paths, pretend that the base directory of your project is all that exists.

So, for example, if your project structure is a `MyProject` folder with children `Assets`, `src`, `bin`, and `util`, and you wanted to refer to some item within the `util` folder, pass along the path like so: `util/my_cool_file.jpeg`