# Understanding java.nio.file.Path.relativize(Path other)

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to familiarize myself with java.nio.file.Path.relativize() to no avail.

I have read the javadocs, and I have seen examples. However, I still cannot get my head around the following example(I use Linux, apologies to window users):

Working directory for program is: /home/userspace/workspace/java8.

With two files: /home/userspace/workspace/java8/zoo.txt and /home/userspace/temp/delete/dictionary.txt

The following program calls Path.relativize():

```
package certExam.java8.ch9NIO.paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class Relativize 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Path relativePathToZoo = Paths.get("zoo.txt");
        Path relativePathToDictionary = Paths.get("../../temp/delete/dictionary.txt");
        System.out.println("relativePathToZoo.relativize(relativePathToDictionary): "+relativePathToZoo.relativize(relativePathToDictionary));
        System.out.println("relativePathToZoo.relativize(relativePathToDictionary).toAbsolutePath(): "+relativePathToZoo.relativize(relativePathToDictionary).toAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("relativePathToZoo.relativize(relativePathToDictionary).toAbsolutePath().normalize(): "+relativePathToZoo.relativize(relativePathToDictionary).toAbsolutePath().normalize());
        System.out.println("relativePathToDictionary.relativize(relativePathToZoo): "+relativePathToDictionary.relativize(relativePathToZoo));
        System.out.println("relativePathToDictionary.relativize(relativePathToZoo).toAbsolutePath().normalize(): "+relativePathToDictionary.relativize(relativePathToZoo).toAbsolutePath().normalize());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
relativePathToZoo.relativize(relativePathToDictionary): ../../../temp/delete/dictionary.txt 
    relativePathToZoo.relativize(relativePathToDictionary).toAbsolutePath(): /home/userspace/workspace/java8/../../../temp/delete/dictionary.txt 
    relativePathToZoo.relativize(relativePathToDictionary).toAbsolutePath().normalize(): /home/temp/delete/dictionary.txt 
    relativePathToDictionary.relativize(relativePathToZoo): ../../../../../zoo.txt 
    relativePathToDictionary.relativize(relativePathToZoo).toAbsolutePath().normalize(): /zoo.txt
```

My question, the bit I cannot understand is: Why does relativePathToDictionary.relativize(relativePathToZoo) output ../../../../../zoo.txt?

When normalized, it would make you think that zoo.txt lives in the root directory.

How does relativize() work out such a deep path? I understand that relativize() works in relation to the current working directory, so it adds **..** to every path. But I am cannot understand, how it worked out the path to zoo.txt in relation to dictionary.txt.

Comment: Remember that relativize returns something that can be passed to resolve, and [resolve assumes its Path represents a directory.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.nio.file.Path-)  Therefore, relativize also assumes its Path is a directory.

Comment: I understood that after some time by just thinking this: I'm navigating on directories on terminal and I want to go from Path A to Path B with a single cd command. That's the output of relativize

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, the current working directory is completely irrelevant. I could reproduce your problem even under Windows, not having any of these files and directories on my system, the only difference being the use of `\\` instead of `/`.

What should `relativize` do? If you have a path like `foo bar baz` and ask for relativizing `foo bar hello`, you’ll get `.. hello` as that’s the path, relative to `foo bar baz` to get to `foo bar hello`, i.e `Paths.get("foo", "bar", "baz").resolve(Paths.get("..", "hello")).normalize()` produces the same path as `Paths.get("foo", "bar", "hello")`, regardless of any real file system structure.

Now you ran into the bug [JDK-6925169](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6925169), as suggested by the user [Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5612858/berger) in a comment. The `Path` implementation does not handle `.` and `..` components correctly in `relativize`, but treats them like any other path component.

So whether you use `Paths.get("..", "..", "temp", "delete", "dictionary.txt")` or `Paths.get("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")`, it makes no difference, in either case, the implementation treats it as five nonmatching path components that have to be removed to resolve to `Paths.get("zoo.txt")`. This applies to both, Windows and Linux. You may verify it with the following platform-independent code:

```
Path relative = Paths.get("zoo.txt");
Path base1 = Paths.get("..", "..", "temp", "delete", "dictionary.txt");
Path base2 = Paths.get("a",  "b",  "c",    "d",      "e");

Path relativized1 = base1.relativize(relative);
System.out.println("relativized1: "+relativized1);
Path relativized2 = base2.relativize(relative);
System.out.println("relativized2: "+relativized2);

Path resolved1 = base1.resolve(relativized1).normalize();
System.out.println("resolved1="+resolved1);
Path resolved2 = base2.resolve(relativized2).normalize();
System.out.println("resolved2="+resolved2);
```

Since `relatize` incorrectly treats all component the same, the relativized paths are the same, but since the `normalize` operation *does* handle the `..` path components, the first resolved path will exhibit the problem whereas the second resolves to the expected `zoo.txt`.

It might be important for the understanding, that all path components, including `dictionary.txt`, are treated like directories. The documentation of `relativize` doesn’t mention that explicitly, but you can derive it from the documented relationship to [`resolve`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.nio.file.Path-), whose documentation says “*… this method considers this path to be a directory*”.

Answer (score 19):

Given the example paths below:

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("java/temp/zoo.txt");
Path p2 = Paths.get("java/bin/elephant.bin");

Path p1Top2 = p1.relativize(p2);
System.out.println(p1Top2);
```

We want to get from `zoo.txt` to `elephant.bin` in this example.
So, let's start at `zoo.txt` and ask ourselves: how do I get from `zoo.txt` to `elephant.bin`.  First I have to go up a directory, so I use "`..`"   Now I'm in `temp`. (Trace the steps with your finger if it helps!). I have to go up one more to `java` so, I use "`..`" again.  Now I'm in `java`.  The directory `bin` is in `java`, so, I go down to it using "`/bin`".  Once more I go down using "`/elephant.bin`". We have arrived at our destination.

Put all of the above steps we took together and you get the output:

```
../../bin/elephant.bin
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I think `p1.relativize(p2)` returning a relative path of `p1` would be more logical, though...

Comment: This is confusing because in the context of Linux, p2 relative to p1, would be just `elephant.bin` without `..` since both the files are in the same directory.

Comment: @GayanWeerakutti What do you mean they are in the same directory? `zoo.txt` is inside the `temp`  directory whereas `elephant.bin` is inside the `bin` directory.

Comment: @MehdiCharife Oh sorry. I thought they are at the same place.