# NIO.2 : understanding the relativize() method

Tags: java, nio, java.nio.file

I'm struggling to understand the `java.nio.file.Path.relativize()` method. I am also aware that a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747896/understanding-java-nio-file-path-relativizepath-other) has been asked, but the answer didn't help me to understand the concept.

Considering the following code snippet:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/Users/somename/documents/Test/cat.html");
Path path2 = Paths.get("/documents/Test/cat.html");
System.out.println((path.relativize(path2))); //output: ../../../../../documents/Test/cat.html
```

Can someone explain to me, using a step-by-step approach, how the `relativize()` method works in this example? Why do I need to go up 5 directories?

Comment: What is your current understanding of what the method is intended to do?

Comment: I understood that after some time by just thinking this:
I'm navigating on directories on terminal and I want to go from Path A to Path B with a single `cd` command. That's the output of relativize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I'll get back to your example at the end of my answer.*

The purpose of relativize() is to be independent from the underlying file system's structure when it comes to adressing/accessing files and folders. You don't have to know in which parent folder/path your app folder is located. You only have to know your app-related file-structure and can use relativize() to access the needed files which may be placed in totally different folders.

**Here's an example:**

Let's say you have created an app. Your simple folder structure is

```
/myApp/app/app.java
/myApp/img/picture1.img
/myApp/sounds/ringtones/bell.mp3
```

Starting the app your working path is

```
<parent path>/myApp/app/
```

If you want to access picture1.img now you don't have to know what its real path (from root down to its actual folder) is. Just use the relative path relativize() provides. It goes like this:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/myApp/app/app.java");
Path path2 = Paths.get("/myApp/img/picture1.img");
System.out.println((path.relativize(path2)));
```

which results in

```
../../img/picture1.img
```

This is the "relative path" from your file app.java to your file picture1.img.

The **first path symbol** stands for the file **app.java** itself

The **second** is for its parent folder **/app**

You are now in the folder

```
/myApp
```

from where you go back down the ladder following the path

```
/img/picture1.img
```

You can get the file using the relative path shown above and you don't have to care about its realPath() which could be, for instance:

```
/Users/me/apps/myApp/img/picture1.img
```

It simply doesn't bother you where your app folder is located as long as you know your own folder structure and access your files with relative paths.

**Now back to your example**

relativize() doesn't know that from your point of view

```
<parent folder>/documents/Test/cat.html
```

is supposed to be the same as

```
/Users/somename/documents/Test/cat.html
```

For relativize() it looks like this

```
/root/Users/somename/documents/Test/cat.html
/root/documents/Test/cat.html
```

So, starting from the upper cat.html you go

1) cat.html = ../

2) Test = ../../

3) documents = ../../../

4) somename = ../../../../

5) Users = ../../../../../

Now you've reached root and now you go down the ladder following the second path.

So the output

**../../../../../documents/Test/cat.html**

is totally correct from relativize()'s point of view.

Did this explanation help you to understand the function of relativize() better?

Comment: this explanation was exactly what I was looking for. I completely understand it now, thank you.