# Why does Path.relativize behave differently on Java 8 and Java 11?

Tags: java, java-8, path, java-11, nio2

Why does the method `relativize` behave differently on [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) and [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11)?

```
Path path1 = Paths.get("/a/./b/../image.png");
Path path2 = Paths.get("/a/file.txt");
Path path = path1.relativize(path2);
System.out.println(path);
```

- [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) (1.8.0_66 to be exact) prints `../../../../file.txt`. [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize-java.nio.file.Path-).
- [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) (11.0.4 to be exact) prints `../file.txt`. [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)).

The JavaDoc description of both versions is equal. I feel the [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) way looks like a correct behavior to me:

- `path1`: `/a/./b/../image.png` normalizes to `/a/b/../image.png` which normalizes to `/a/image.png`
- `path2`: `/a/file.txt`
- the way to *navigate* from `/a/image.png` and `/a/file.txt` is `../file.txt`

**Questions**

1. How is the [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) way supposed to be calculated? Doesn't it normalize the path? I don't understand how to get the result *from head*.
2. Why is there a difference between these two versions that is not documented at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37747896/2711488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows based source-code answer here.

From the observation of the source codes (let's take a look at `sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath`, one of the implementations of `Path`) in [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) is has additional code including *normalization* compared to [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8).

- [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) [`sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b60/jdk/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPath.java) source code at GitHub
- [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) [`sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11%2B0/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPath.java) source code at GitHub

The key line of the latter implementation starts at the **line 411**, so basically, the latter implementation *normalizes* the paths before taking into calculation of the relative path:

```
WindowsPath base = this;
if (base.hasDotOrDotDot() || child.hasDotOrDotDot()) {
    base = base.normalize();
    child = child.normalize();
}
```

Digging further, the implementation changes between [`jdk8-b120`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPath.java) (source) and [`jdk-9+95`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-9+95/jdk/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPath.java) (source). Since the modular system was introduced, **both** the classes implementation and location differ:

- Java 8 and below: `/jdk/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPath.java`
- Java 9 and above: `/jdk/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPath.java`

> How is the [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) way supposed to be calculated? Doesn't it normalize the path? I don't understand how to get the result *from head*.

The most straightforward way to go is to *normalize both paths* first before relativizing them. But I have no idea whether it completely covers all the `java.nio.file.Path` implementations and is safe to do so.

```
Path path = path1.normalize().relativize(path2.normalize());
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this bug will answer your question:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066943

This affected relativizing paths containing . or .. and was fixed for Java 9.
So that's why you see a difference between 8 and 11.

Comment: Interestingly this was already reported in 2010 as [JDK-6925169](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6925169), but was apparently never fixed (and only resolved as "Duplicate" in 2018).