# How to get files from a project folder

Tags: java, file

The folder is `/src/img`. I need to get all file names(`png` files) from `img` folder and all subfolders.I dont know the full path to the folder so i need only to focus the project resourse. I need them in array. Using Java8 and Eclipse Mars.
So far this works:

```
try {


Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/fixxxer/NetBeansProjects/Installer/src/img/")).forEach(filePath -> {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                System.out.println(filePath);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InstallFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The problem is that the folder need to be called like this:
`/img` cause it is inside the project
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-a-relative-path-in-java). 
Here, I am assuming that `Installer` is your project name. Otherwise, you can edit the relative path according to your project setup.

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(".//src//img//")).forEach(filePath -> {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                    System.out.println(filePath);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place your file

```
test.png
```

under

```
/src/resources/org/example
```

you can access it from your class

```
org.example.InstallFrame
```

using

```
final URL resource = InstallFrame.class.getResource("test.png");
```

respectively

```
final InputStream resourceAsStream = InstallFrame.class.getResourceAsStream("test.png");
```

Comment: I need to get all files, not only one

Comment: @Ralfi Do you know their respective names or just an arbitrary number of files? The first is manageable by using a list of names, the second is not covered by the class-loader API for loading resources and you have to think of a naming/directory scheme for yourself (i.e. using `/tmp/installer` or any other determined directory name usable by any machine you're running your program on or make the path configurable for users of your program).

Comment: i dont know the names sadly. I need to get all the files. Can you show me example of class loader api in my case?

Comment: No, as I wrote that "the second is not covered by the class-loader API for loading resources".

Answer (score 0):

First find the base path and then use in your code

```
 String basePath = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("").getPath();

 //move basepath to the path where img directory 
 //present in your project using ".." 
 //like basepath = basepath+"..\\..\\img"+

    Files.walk(Paths.get(testPath)).forEach(filePath -> {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
            System.out.println(filePath);
        }
    });
```