# Selenium Upload a file - any method to mention the file path?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Uploading a file scenario, i am mentioning the file path as like "D:\Workspace\MyProject\InputData\file1.jpg". Mentioning full system file path even the upload file is inside my project source folder.

```
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("D:\Workspace\MyProject\InputData\file1.jpg"); 
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
```

But while I run my code in another machine - I need to update file path.

I tried following code because upload file is inside the source folder, but it hasn't worked

```
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("InputData\file1.jpg"); 
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
```

Is it any other method to mention the file path (as like only mention source folder file path) without mentioning the system whole path?

Comment: One solution is to have the user of your program input the file path at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response.

Finally I found a solution to the above question. I have used following code to fix it..

```
   //This will return the build absolute path in ss variable
   StringSelection ss=new StringSelection(uploadfile().getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+"TestJpegFile.jpeg");
   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);


//Call this function while setup your path 
public File uploadfile()
    {
        File datadir=new File("InputData\\images\\");
           try
           {
               if(!datadir.exists())
               {
                   datadir.mkdir();
               }
           }catch(Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return datadir;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the relative path for the file. For example, if you are writing above code in a class **A** which is under package **X** of your **src** directory, then you can specify path in following way:

```
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("././InputData/file1.jpg"); 
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
```

For more details about how to specify **relative** paths in Java, refer to [How to define a relative path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-a-relative-path-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

you can find your current path first

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

then find the file path base on your current path

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

```
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"<apend your path for the file>");
```