# Where to use resolve() and relativize() method of java.nio.file.Path class?

Tags: java, path, resolve

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/Users/jack/Documents/text1.txt");
Path p2 = Paths.get("/Users/jack/text2.txt");
Path result1 = p1.resolve(p2);
Path result2 = p1.relativize(p2);

System.out.println("result1: "+result1);
System.out.println("result2: "+result2);
```

OUTPUT

```
result1: /Users/jack/text2.txt
result2: ../../text2.txt
```

I cannot understand how `resolve()` and `relativize()` works?

What is the actual use of `result1` and `result2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the code snippets from my code base that help you to understand the use of the resolve() method

```
private File initUsersText() throws Exception
{
    Path dir = testdir.getPath().toRealPath();
    FS.ensureDirExists(dir.toFile());
    File users = dir.resolve("users.txt").toFile();

    writeUser( users );
    return users;
}


private File initUsersText() throws Exception
{
    Path dir = testdir.getPath().toRealPath();
    FS.ensureDirExists(dir.toFile());
    File users = dir.resolve("users.txt").toFile();

    writeUser( users );
    return users;
}
```

And these are the examples of the use of relativize()

```
public ScopePath pathToClassName(Path file) {
    if (!isValidClass(file))
        return null;

    Path relativePath = root.relativize(root.resolve(file));
    String withoutExtension = removeExtension(relativePath.toString());
    return new ScopePath(withoutExtension.replace(File.separator, "."));
}


private String getRelativePath(Path p) {
    String relativePath = packageDir.relativize(p)
            .toString();

    if (File.separator.equals("\\")) {
        relativePath = relativePath.replace("\\", "/");
    }

    return relativePath;
}
```

Comment: Why is `initUsersText` written twice? :)

Answer (score 52):

> I cannot understand how resolve() and relativize() method works?

[`Path resolve(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.nio.file.Path-) resolves the given path against `this` path.
[`Path relativize(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize-java.nio.file.Path-) constructs a relative path of the given path against `this` path .
These are reverse operations.

---

**Path resolve(Path other)**

In the general use case of `resolve()`, you want to return a new `Path` object where you will join this `Path` object to the `Path` parameter that is a relative `Path` such as :

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/Users/jack");
Path p2 = Paths.get("text1.txt");
Path result1 = p1.resolve(p2);
```

Here `result1` will be the path join of `p1` and `p2`, that is : `/Users/jack/text1.txt`.

In your example the parameter passed to the method is not a relative `Path` but an absolute :

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/Users/jack/Documents/text1.txt");
Path p2 = Paths.get("/Users/jack/text2.txt");
Path result1 = p1.resolve(p2);
```

It  makes no sense to "append" a `Path` to another if the second is an absolute `Path`.
So the javadoc considers that in this case the parameter is returned as result of `resolve()` :

> If the other parameter is an absolute path then this method trivially
>   returns other.

**Path relativize(Path other)**

The doc says more specifically :

> This method attempts to construct a relative path that when resolved
>   against `this` path, yields a path that locates the same file as the
>   given path.

It means that the returned `Path` is the relative path of the `Path` parameter relatively to  `this` `Path`.

For example, if `this` path is `"/a/b"` and the given path is `"/a/b/c/d"` then the resulting relative path would be `"c/d"`.

We will check that with your example :

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/Users/jack/Documents/text1.txt");
Path p2 = Paths.get("/Users/jack/text2.txt");
Path result2 = p1.relativize(p2);   
// result2= ../../text2.txt
```

The `../../text2.txt` Path is expected as result as the relative path produced ( `../../text2.txt`) resolved against `this` path (`/Users/jack/Documents/text1.txt`) yields a path that locates the same file as the given path (`/Users/jack/text2.txt`) :

```
Paths.of("/Users/jack/Documents/text1.txt").resolve("../../text2.txt")

returns -> /Users/jack/text2.txt
```

Comment: `resolve` sounds like a strange name to depict the process of joining paths. Why not use the name `join` instead?

Answer (score 7):

`resolve()`: Joins two paths.

`relativize ()`:  construct a path from one location in the file system to another location.

Output explanation:

`result1: /Users/jack/text2.txt`: because you passed in an absolute path, `resolve()` returns the passed in the path as is if it is an absolute path.

`result2: ../../text2.txt`: to get to `/Users/jack/text2.txt` from `/Users/jack/Documents/text1.txt"` you need to to go two levels up, and then just select `text2.txt file.

Answer (score 5):

### [Path::resolve](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)) - Resolve the given path against this path.

> If the other parameter is an absolute path then this method trivially returns other.

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/usr");
Path p2 = Paths.get("/etc");
Path p3 = p1.resolve(p2); // returns /etc
```

> If other is an empty path then this method trivially returns this path.

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/usr");
Path p2 = Paths.get("");
Path p3 = p1.resolve(p2); // returns /usr
```

Otherwise this method considers this path to be a directory and resolves the given path against this path.

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/usr");
Path p2 = Paths.get("local");
Path p3 = p1.resolve(p2); // returns /usr/local
```

### [Path::relativize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)) - Constructs a relative path between this path and a given path.

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/usr");
Path p2 = Paths.get("/usr/local");
Path p3 = p1.relativize(p2); // returns local
```

This also means that

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/usr");
Path p2 = Paths.get("/usr/../usr/local");
Path p3 = p1.relativize(p2); // returns local
```

But if the two paths are equal returns an empty path

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/usr");
Path p2 = Paths.get("/usr/../usr");
Path p3 = p1.relativize(p2); // returns empty path
```

Answer (score 1):

The `resolve(Path)` is a method for creating a new Path by joining an existing path to the current path.

```
Path path1 = Paths.get("/test1/../test2");
Path path2 = Paths.get("test3");
System.out.println(path1.resolve(path2));
```

The result will be: `/test1/../test2/test3`

In fact, the method relativize(Path) is used for constructing the relative path from one Path object to another:

```
Path path1= Paths.get("E:\\test1");
Path path2= Paths.get("E:\\test2\\test3");
System.out.println(path1.relativize(path2));
System.out.println(path2.relativize(path1));
```

The result will be:

```
..\test2\test3  relative path from path1 to path2
..\..\test1     relative path from path2 to path1
```