# Improper Access Control Authorization -Checkmarx - File Read/Write Operation

Tags: java, file-io, checkmarx

I am using the Checkmarx security tool to scan my code. I am getting:

> Improper Access Control Authorization

on read/write method while writing data to output stream from file.

```
private ByteArrayOutputStream createToByteArray(String fileName) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            int len = is.read(buf);
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while (len != -1) {
                os.write(buf, 0, len);
                len = is.read(buf);
            }
            return os;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkmarx Improper Resource Access Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824178/checkmarx-improper-resource-access-authorization)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is getting low severity at below specific part in checkmarx.

> Paths.get(fileName)

then try using resolve() method like

> `Paths.get(fileName).resolve("")`

resolve () -> this method is used to resolve the given path against this path.

for more info on resolve(), refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50551920/where-to-use-resolve-and-relativize-method-of-java-nio-file-path-class)

Answer (score 0):

You expect the **user** can read a file from the **file system**, by `path`, and convert it to `ByteStream`. Fine.

But what if the user giving you an absolute file path? Or relative one (`../../.ssh/id_rsa`, for example)?

No matter who is sending the request, the access permissions of the request is actually the **server** access permissions (because this code runs on the server, of course).

So you need to validate the **user** access permissions, for avoiding **Improper Access Control Authorization**.

Example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57863422/839513):

```java
if (user.equals("admin")){
   try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName))) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Also, my suggestion is to remove any **relative path** from the `filename` input path.

Comment: user is already validated with Spring Security Authentication and Authorization at global level. I assume it is bad design to validate it everytime  we are doing read/write operation.