# How can I access a txt file with a relative path?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, relative-path

I'm using IntelliJ Idea and I try to read a txt file from a different location in the project. I don't want to use an absolute path like C:/User/... because if the project is moved to a different location the project wouldn't work anymore. I'm not sure how the path should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using relative Paths, this will generally also mean that it will not work anymore once you are changing directory structure.

Example (I am assuming Windows here):

The java-application resides `C:\Tools` . You are using a relative Path (`..\file.txt`). This would access `C:\file.txt` (`..` moves up one directory).
If you moved the App to `C:\Tools\JavaApp` it wouldn't work anymore, since `..\file.txt` now points to `C:\Tools\file.txt`).

You have several options (three just from the top of my head; there are multiple ways to do this) to achieve what you want:

1. Use an alias to access the file. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/217504/is-there-a-list-of-windows-special-directories-shortcuts-like-temp) is a list of windows-shortcuts that will work (I am assuming that you are using Windows). For example: Save the file to `%appdata%`, and it will always save to the current user's appdata folder. To resolve the windows shortcut to an absolute path in Java, use `System.getenv("APPDATA")`.
2. Read the file from the program's working directory
   This is probably what you meant by using relative paths:
   The current working directory of a java application is the directory the program is being run from. This will require you to place the file to be read in the same folder as your project/jar-file, or to use relative paths to navigate to the file's location, for example a sub-folder in your working directory where you would place the file.
3. Use a .properties file to declare the file location
   You could also read the file location from a properties file, however you can only change the path at compile time. [Here's](https://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/) an article on how to use .properties-files.

Comment: If I want to use the windows-shortcut how shut the path look like? For example I have the File test.txt and it is save in the appdata/roming folder and I want to use the %appdata%.

Comment: Simply call `System.getenv("APPDATA")`. This will return the absolute path of the appdata folder as a string, and you can use this absolute path just like you would any other.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-a-relative-path-in-java)

You can access files with relative path like this way:

```
File file = new File("..\\..\\file.txt");
String fileAbsolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

*Hint: This only works if the file is embedded to the project.*