# FileInputStream doesn't work with the relative path

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I tried to create an object from `FileInputStream` and pass the relative value of a file to its constructor, but it doesn't work properly and threw a `FileNotFoundException`

```
try {
   InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/files/somefile.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
   System.out.println("File not found !");
}
```

Comment: /files is not a relative path. Do you mean ./files?

Comment: That's not a relative path. It's an absolute path.

Comment: Either "./files/" or "files/" should work as a relative path.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `/` at the start will make the path absolute instead of relative.

Try removing the leading `/`, so replace:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/files/somefile.txt");
```

with:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("files/somefile.txt");
```

If you're still having trouble, try making sure the program is running from where you think by [checking the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java):

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: i found same error but with russian filename only what sould i do. My file path /storage/emulated/0/fourth_ррссттууффххцц.txt  pls help

Comment: No, doesn't work if the file is in the same directory as the InputStream instance code.

Answer (score 8):

The other posters are right the path you are giving is not a relative path. You could potentially do something like `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Path relative to the current class")`.  This would allow you to load a file as a stream based on a path relative to the class from which you call it.

See the Java API for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 5):

1. this is not a relative path, it is an absolute path.
2. If you are on Windows you need to add your drive letter before your path:

`InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/files/somefile.txt");`

windows doesn't support the `/` symbol as "root"

If you want to load a file thatt you'll put in your JAR, you need to use

```
getClass().getResource("path to your file");
```

or

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("path to your file");
```

Comment: files is a package in the src folder of the project , and I want to make this folder or package part of the final .jar file

Comment: ok, but your path is not relative, so you need to use a relative path OR specify the absolute path for your file

Comment: okay , could you give me a code to get the absolute path of the final .jar file :)