# Issues with creating class with image file path as argument

Tags: java, class

I am attempting to make a class which can take a string with an image path and set it as this objects image. I have done it manually before, i.e. creating a new class with an extends main class, but this will get out of hand quickly. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Sprite {
private int x;
    private int y;
    private ImageIcon ia;
    private URL loc;
    private Image image;

public Sprite(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public Sprite(int x, int y, String imgLoc) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    URL loc = this.getClass().getResource(imgLoc); //problem area is here
    ia = new ImageIcon(loc); //and here
    image = ia.getImage();
    this.setImage(image);
}
```

When I had a child class, It worked in the child classI put in something like this:

```
public class Dude extends Sprite {
   public Dude (intx, int y) {
      super(x, y);

      URL loc = this.getClass().getResource("images/dude.png");
      ia = new ImageIcon(loc);
      image = ia.getImage();
      this.setImage(image);
   }
}
```

But when I try to use the second Sprite Constructor, it gave me an

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at Sprite.<init>(Sprite.java:26)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Whoops, forgot to include the error I ran into it. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Your resource does not exist.

Comment: Just to be sure, do getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(res) instead, i had problems in the past dont remember why

Comment: I tried it, and it did not seem to help.

Comment: What string argument did you use for the second Sprite constructor? I know it sounds stupid but is the file path correct (like slashes, missing extension and so on)?

Comment: Looks like that solved the problem. Had to comb through my code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the solution. It turns out that I had slightly got the image path wrong, along the lines of:

```
//Image is called: "images/dude2.png"
//But I called it: "images/dude.png"
```

I guess the lesson to learn from this is to make absolutely sure everything is called correctly.

Comment: The `NullPointerException` can be avoided by checking for `null` as well.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/15581779/3196753.