# Java getResource() not working for including resources in .jar file

Tags: java, jar, resources

I know this issue has been discussed a bazillion times but unfortunately I cannot get past this. 
I am trying to load an image that is in my resources folder. When I use:

```
    public static BufferedImage[] readImages() {

       BufferedImage img = null;
       try { 
         img = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/imgs/map.png"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
```

(see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SUHl.png)) and run the program, the image is loaded as it should. However, when I create the .jar file and try to run it, the image is not accessed and I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: src image is null at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp.filter(AffineTransformOp.java:214)
>   at MyClass.readImages(MyClass.java:100)
>   at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:21)

Then I try using the getResource() method, but that doesn't load the image and I get the **NullPointerException** error.

```
    public static BufferedImage[] readImages() {

       BufferedImage img = null;
       try { 
         img = ImageIO.read(MyClass.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/imgs/map.png"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at MyClass.readImages(MyClass.java:92)
>   at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:21)

Does anyone have an idea on how to include the image to the .jar just by using "new File(filename)" or how to fix the NullPointerException?

---

**EDIT**:  The solution to my problem was:

```
img = ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("map.png"));
```

with map.jpg being  in "MyProject/resources/map.jpg" and the script in "MyProject/src/MyClass.java".

---

Comment: Simple: your image path is wrong. You don't show us this path, so it's hard to help.

Comment: [Link to many similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+null+getresource)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have attached a screenshot to show my structure, the image is in the source folder.

Comment: Read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581687/class-getresource-returns-null) please. It will answer your question and help you solve your problem.