# java can't access resources folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a structure like ths (using IntelliJ

[image]

When I try and access items in the resources folder I get a null pointer exception:

```
private Icon bishopB = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("icons/bishopb.gif") );
```

exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at chess.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:21)
    at chess.ChessGame.<init>(ChessGame.java:14)
    at chess.ChessGame.main(ChessGame.java:28)
```

when debugging it seems to be looking for the resource chess/icons/bishopb.gif

Comment: Try using `getClass().getResource("/icons/bishopb.gif")` instead.  Using `"icons/bishopb.gif"` is actually relative path based on the current package

Comment: I did try that but it gives me the same error

Comment: The crack the resulting Jar open and make sure the resources are been included AND they are in the expected path - Jars are just zip files, so you can change the file extension and unzip it

Comment: OP never said they were using Spring Boot - but you never know with what creativity some of this is created.

Comment: @Tino - is this a Sping Boot app generated with starter.spring.io?

Comment: No this isn't spring boot

Comment: You might find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15581779/9078341

Comment: Thanks @RandyCasburn - changing to getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("icons/bishopb.gif") seemed to fix it

Answer (score -1):

Use `getClass().getClassLoader()` if you want to use full paths staring from the resource roots.