# How to "really" draw images in a Java app

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm experimenting with graphics in Java, creating a domino game.  However, I have run into another mysterious little "challenge"... I think I really ticked off the IDE this time

Anyway here is my code:

```
// In the main class
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GameBoard extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame game = new JFrame();
        game.setTitle("Domino");
        game.setSize(800, 600);
        game.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        Domino double6 = new Domino("images/double_6.png",16,16,'H',6,6);
        game.add(double6);
        // Create pieces
        game.setVisible(true);
    }
}

// The game piece class
package domino;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Domino extends JPanel {
    // Instance variables for each piece
    public int n1, n2, x, y;
    public char position;
    // n1 is the first number, n2 is the second number, x and y are coordinates, position refers to horizontal or vertical (ideally would be a different image for each direction)
    public BufferedImage img = null;
    public String fileName;

    // Constructor
    public Domino(String fileName, int x, int y, char position, int n1, int n2) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.n1 = n1;
        this.n2 = n2;
        this.position = position;
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (this.position == 'H') {
        try {
            // Here's where the trouble appears to rear its ugly head...
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
            g.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, null);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // This code was generated by the system - it wouldn't even let me do the drawImage code about without a try/catch.
            Logger.getLogger(Domino.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
            // If all else fails I can at least draw the game pieces manually.
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 32, 64);
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, when I run it, I get this:

```
run:
Jul 04, 2013 11:33:13 PM domino.Domino paintComponent
SEVERE: null
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at domino.Domino.paintComponent(Domino.java:43)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5228)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3877)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Jul 04, 2013 11:33:14 PM domino.Domino paintComponent
SEVERE: null
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at domino.Domino.paintComponent(Domino.java:43)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5228)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3877)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

So I did some research.  First, I went to the Java/Oracle website and found their tutorial 
on drawing images (and in fact my code very closely based on theirs, at least the 
try/catch part).  Then I tried to remove the try/catch thing to see what the exception 
would be (I was 99% sure there would be one, lol).  Well my IDE (NetBeans) responded by 
bugging out and basically forcing me to use one.  So then I went into the project folder 
and checked to make sure the file was in the right place (it was).  So just for the heck 
of it, I copied it into every other folder in the project to see if that would help.  It 
didn't.

So it's painfully obvious I've done something wrong, and for whatever reason Java can't or 
won't read the file, even though it exists and is in correct location (and now every 
location), but I have no idea what else to do about it.

So, as always, I'm open to any ideas, suggestions or other information.  Thanks in advance. : )

Comment: Is this one file or two?

Comment: Where does the file exist?  Is it suppose to be an embedded resource in your Jar file or does it exist on the hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you take the images/ part out of the path, and make sure the file is in the same directory as your exe?  So, instead of

```
Domino double6 = new Domino("images/double_6.png",16,16,'H',6,6);
```

try

```
Domino double6 = new Domino("double_6.png",16,16,'H',6,6);
```

That should check the same directory as where you are running your program from.

Comment: It's java - there is no exe.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! :)    And thanks to everyone who contributed.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: What was the OS you were working with? Maybe you should have used the `pathSeparator` method from `File` class

Answer (score 4):

Check what's your current working directory: [Getting the current working directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java). It should be the folder that contains `images` folder, but probably isn't, hence the exception.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
```

and according to the stack trace it happens when you call ImageIO.read in line 43 of Domino.java.

Make sure that the file you want to load exists, is readable and that the relative path (images/double_6.png) is relative to the directory you execute the program in.