# Java graphic as an object/class

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm sorry this is probably way too basic to be on here, but it's a subject I've been struggling with for about a month now and I don't know where else to go (as far as I know there is no "noob overflow", lol).

I'm trying to create a class that would:

```
1.  put an image on a window (a JFrame, JPanel or other container)
2.  be able to support keyboard and mouse listeners
3.  could have multiple instances in the same container
```

So anyway I've tried all the usual places - Google, YouTube, the official Java site (sorry forgot the URL) and of course here on Stack Overflow - but haven't been able to find anything even remotely similar to what I'm trying to do.

Of course, I've also considered the possiblity that maybe it can't be done at all.  There doesn't seem to be any kind of standard "JImage" or "JGraphic" that works like JButton or JLabel, and for whatever reason graphics requires a completely different list of (extremely involved) processes and procedures.  As an example, in this post: [How to "really" draw images in a Java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482992/how-to-really-draw-images-in-a-java-app) - it took me 60+ lines of code and 2 classes to just come close.  That project didn't work in the end because for some reason it would only let me create one instance (even it you created 2-4 in the main method, it would only display the last one you told it to add).

But anyway, assuming that I'm not trying to "re-invent the wheel" here and it is actually possible (in Java), does anyone have an idea as to how (or at least know of a better site to study it)?  Unfortunately most of the sites I've visited tend to assume you know all the inner workings of images (I know what a pixel is but that's about it - Buffers, Rastars etc. are still beyond me).  It would be absolutely outstanding if there were a site that would explain it in layman's terms, if such a site exists.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a plain old JLabel.

Regarding your requirements:

> put an image on a window (a JFrame, JPanel or other container).

You can give a JLabel an ImageIcon of the image of interest and it will display it. This can then be easily placed in any other container such as a JPanel or JFrame.

> be able to support keyboard and mouse listeners

Any component that extends JComponent, such as a JLabel allows for use of MouseListener, MouseMotionListener and can listen for keyboard input via Key Bindings.

> could have multiple instances in the same container

You can add as many as you'd like to any container. Just be cognizant and respectful of the layout managers in use.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know labels could hold images (I figured label = text/a String) but when I looked up the ImageIcon I got it to work in seconds!  I just spent half the day trying to figure this out, so this is a huge help. :)