# How to call the code relative to the present directory.

Tags: java, file

I have a code like this:

```
String[] cmd = { "osascript","mylocation" };
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
process.waitFor();
```

The location `myLocation` file is inside my `script` folder. This class is in `src` folder. I tried `../script/file` which is not working.

How can I call the file in `script` folder?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc for [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29)

```
    public Process exec(String[] cmdarray,
           String[] envp,
           File dir)
             throws IOException
```

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process with the specified environment and working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do provide the relative path as given below:

```
    String[] cmd = { "..\\script\\osascript", "mylocation" };
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    process.waitFor();
```