# Get file current local folder and search inside it

Tags: java, string, file, directory

I'm in doubt about something. I'm developing a Java Desktop application and I have a problem.

I need to **get the current local folder** that my application (jar file) is in user system. And after this, **to search inside of this same folder** for some files (like all .txt file, for example). And finally, **get the name of only one** of this files and converts to *string*.

Someone can help me?
Antecipate thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I don't found any code that be a sample to I understand

Answer (score 0):

May be the `getCanonicalPath()` and `getProperty()` functions could help you, since you don't show any code I can't make you any example, but may be looking [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_getcanonicalpath.htm) could help you a little.

And also there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

Comment: Thanks. Now I found the code to get the current local folder: `String path = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();`