# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail - ssh key

Tags: java, mysql, ssh

Trying to connect to mySQL database with ssh key file. Here is my setup:

```
public class DBconnect {

private Connection con;
private Statement st;
private ResultSet rs;

String strSshUser = "XXXX";          // SSH loging username
String strSshPassword = "XXXX";      // SSH login password
String strSshHost = "XXXX";          // hostname or ip or SSH server
int nSshPort = 22;                   // remote SSH host port number
String strRemoteHost = "XXXX";  // hostname or ip of your database server
int nLocalPort = 3366;          // local port number use to bind SSH tunnel
int nRemotePort = 3306;         // remote port number of your database 
String strDbUser = "XXXX";      // database loging username
String strDbPassword = "XXXX";          // database login password
String privateKey = "/directory/inside/package/.pem-key";

 private static void doSshTunnel( String strSshUser, String strSshPassword, String strSshHost, int nSshPort, String strRemoteHost, int nLocalPort, int nRemotePort,String privateKey ) throws JSchException
  {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    //jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
    Session session = jsch.getSession( strSshUser, strSshHost, 22 );
    session.setPassword( strSshPassword );


    final Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put( "StrictHostKeyChecking", "no" );
    session.setConfig( config );


    session.connect();
    session.setPortForwardingL(nLocalPort, strRemoteHost, nRemotePort);
  }

public DBconnect() {
    try{

        doSshTunnel(strSshUser, strSshPassword, strSshHost, nSshPort, strRemoteHost, nLocalPort, nRemotePort, privateKey);

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(""jdbc:mysql:XXXX:3306/XXXX","XXXX","XXXX"");

        st = con.createStatement();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }
}
```

I get the error -- com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail -- when I try this, and when I comment out -- //jsch.addIdentity(privateKey) -- I get the error of -- java.io.FileNotFoundException: "/directory/inside/package/.pem-key"(No such file or directory). Am I even approaching this correctly? I think this is the proper way to connect to my mysql db through ssh but I dont know how to include my .pem key file to complete the connection.

Comment: are you specifying an absolute vs a relative path?

Comment: relative path because im going to have to create a jar file for others to use

Comment: i think i got the same failure of directory not found when i specified the absolute path as well.

Comment: If the path begins with a `/`, then that isn't a relative path Try beginning it with `./`. Also, check where the working directory of the program is. It might not be where you think it is

Comment: so i right clicked my file and copied the path file, which is the package directory of project; i tried what you suggested and this is what I get -- Error: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./NewCustomer/src/qa-cloud.pem (No such file or directory)

Comment: check the working directory of your project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: its saying null, I placed the file I needed directly into the package and when I use this code:System.out.println("Working Directory = "+System.getProperty("qa-cloud.pem")); i get null

Comment: I think you have to send the string "user.dir", not the filename of the file you want to find.

Comment: Are you trying to get Jsch to use a key file stored in a jar? `Jsch.addIdentity(String)` reads a key from a file in the filesystem. If you want to use a key from a resource, you'll have to read the key resource yourself and then call one of the other `addIdentity()` functions.