# Where is the H2 database stored?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, h2

I am trying to use an `H2` database with `Java`. I cannot seem to find out where the data is being written.

The database URL I am giving is: `jdbc:h2:/db/bh`.

I am connecting with the database using `Java` like so:
`dbObj.setDBConnection(DriverManager.getConnection(hObj.getDBUrl(), hObj.getDBUsername(), hObj.getDBPassword()));`
where DB URL is given above.
Username: sa
Password:   (empty).

I am running the `jar` from within the following folder:
`C:\work\sampleH2\sampleH2.jar`

My understanding of the FAQ section of H2 says that the database `bh` will be found in the folder `db/` of the folder `sampleH2`. But that is not the case. Where can I find it?

Comment: By default, h2 runs in-memory.

Comment: There is no "default", the JDBC url determines if it is created on disc or in memory. Judging by the path in that url (/db/bh) it will be created in c:\db\bh on Windows systems.

Comment: @Gimby: Thank you for your reply. You are correct. How do I ensure the db is stored in the db folder of the path I am running the jar from: C:\work\sampleH2\db\bh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html there is a difference between storing in:

- relative path (somewhere under current directory): jdbc:h2:test
- absolute path (somewhere under root directory): jdbc:h2:/data/test

so i would look for it on your main drive (probably c:) under path you specified

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried changing the url to "db/bh" but that has had no effect.

Comment: Also, in the document you linked to, current working directory is specified as "current(!) working directory". Why the exclamation mark? And how is current working directory identified?

Comment: i guess it's a current working directory for your java application. more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java