# How to trigger a handler class when consuming web-service in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

Using `Axis 1.4` I built client application that will consume external server services.

The server application response with soap message that include header tag along with body tag.

My problem with the header tag, I am trying to find away to get the `header` element.

**What is done so far:**

I found that I need to use a handler that extends `BasicHandler` using this class I can get the header tag. source: [Dealing with SOAP Headers in Axis](http://blog.harezmi.com.tr/dealing-with-soap-headers-in-axis/)

But how to make this handler work when consuming web-service? I mean how to invoke this handler when ever I am **receiving** response from server to get its `header`.

Some blogs suggest I need to use `.wsdd` file. I am using Jdeveloper 11g with weblogic 10.3.6 environment where I am only aware of `web.xml` file for configuration.

**Question:** How to link those information(handler class, `.wsdd` file and `web.xml`) to gather and make the handler works to get the header tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best start was to check Axis guide on: [Apache-Axis Reference Guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html) where you will have an overview of the work flow.

To configure handlers to be trigger from the client side you need to do the following:

**1-** Create handler class basically something similar to the following:

```
package mypackge;

import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import org.apache.axis.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler;
import org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeader;
import org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement;

public class SoapHeaderConsumerHandler
  extends BasicHandler
{
  public void invoke(MessageContext messageContext)
    throws AxisFault
  {
    // Your logic for request or response handling goes here. 
    // Basically you need to make use of the parameter
   // messageContext where you can access the soap header and body tags.
  }
}
```

**2-** Create the `client-config.wsdd` file. it will look like the following:

```
<deployment
    xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">
    <globalConfiguration>
        <responseFlow>
            <handler name="log" type="java:mypackge.SoapHeaderConsumerHandler"/>
        </responseFlow>
    </globalConfiguration>
    <transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender"/>
</deployment>
```

You can see that I am using only handlers for the incoming response from the server side. So when ever the client application receive a response from the server the handler class `SoapHeaderConsumerHandler` will be triggered and the method invoke will be called by default.

**Note:** if you want to access the outgoing request before send it to the server you need to add extra tag for `<requestFlow>` to add request handler.

Check [Deployment(WSDD) Reference from Axis guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html#Deployment_WSDD_Reference):

**3-** Where to place the `client-config.wsdd` file ?

You should place the `.wsdd` file in the working directory. You can easily find out the working directory location using :

```
System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

**Source:** [Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

**UPDATE:**

I found out that it is not necessary to put the `client-config.wsdd` file in the working directory. You can specify the path of this file in your code as follow:

```
System.setProperty("axis.ClientConfigFile", "[Path goes here]\\client-config.wsdd");
```

You just need to place the `.wsdd` file there.

**Extra Useful Links:**

[Where to place the client-config.wsdd file in Railo](http://www.blayter.com/john/index.cfm/2012/12/13/Where-to-place-the-clientconfigwsdd-file-in-Railo)

[V Axis handler](http://javaonline.free.fr/Frameworks/Axis/part-5.php)  This is an example for the server side handlers.

[Dealing with SOAP Headers in Axis](http://blog.harezmi.com.tr/dealing-with-soap-headers-in-axis/)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid file location problems you can programatically configure axis :

```
    ConsultationServiceLocator stub = new ConsultationServiceLocator();
    SimpleProvider clientConfig = new SimpleProvider();
    SoapHeaderConsumerHandler logHandler = new SoapHeaderConsumerHandler();
    SimpleChain reqHandler = new SimpleChain();
    SimpleChain respHandler = new SimpleChain();
    reqHandler.addHandler(logHandler);
    respHandler.addHandler(logHandler);
    Handler pivot = new HTTPSender();
    Handler transport = new SimpleTargetedChain(reqHandler, pivot, respHandler);
    clientConfig.deployTransport(HTTPTransport.DEFAULT_TRANSPORT_NAME, transport);
```