# What does axis add to XML before it is sent?

Tags: java, xml, soap, axis

I'm tracing a bug in some Apache Axis 1.4 code. Some XML is generated, it's set as the vXML of a stub, and then the stub is sent out over the network. At some point before it's sent out, some SOAP headers, an envelope and a few other enclosing tags are added.

**What determines what gets added to the XML before it gets sent out over the wire in Apache Axis 1.2?**

**How can I change the SOAP headers and the other enclosing tags?**

Answer (score 1):

The structure of SOAP messages is defined by the [JAX-WS specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxws-2.2-mrel3-evalu-oth-JSpec/jaxws-2_2-mrel3-spec.pdf).

To change the message on a "physical" level you can use handlers. See for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854697/how-to-trigger-a-handler-class-when-consuming-web-service-in-java).