# Java check if the application is getting run from a specific phat

Tags: java

As the title says, is there a way to get the current location of the .jar that is begun open, for example i have a file Test.jar and when i run it on desktop it works but when i run it from my documents it just will don't open.

An example of how can it be structured:

```
if(location == Desktop){
   //Do stuff here
} else {
System.exit(0);
}
```

Thx for the help! and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Are you sure you want the location of the jar file? Maybe you want the current working directory instead?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/7603444/1980909

Comment: I see from the other post that @AdrianLeonhard put that ` System.getProperty("user.dir"))` will print out the complete path where the jar file is initiate is that correct ?