# Read CSV file from package

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file that I copy in my work package,  I want read it from my package not a path on my PC in order  to not change the link every time I change my PC but I do not know how do this, I tried a solution that did not work for me this is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CSV obj = new CSV();
    obj.run();
}

public void run() {
    String csvFile = "C:/Users/Intervalle tech/Desktop/SV.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    //URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/BocOperations/src/operations/SV.csv");
    //File file = new File(url.getPath());

    try {
      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          // use comma as separator
          // String[] Element = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
          System.out.println( line );
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can load the CSV file from the resources folder.
It is at the same root than your java folder, and has to have the same structure (packages). Put your CSV file here. Then load it with the code in the answer below, without path (not needed because it is now a resource file). 
It will be loaded as a resource. Just make sure that when you package your java project, it'll include resources fodler.

Comment: @Aeldred It is need to have a corresponding builder for `resources` folder, for an example Maven builder (in Eclipse).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275143/java-io-filenotfoundexception-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-cvs-fi/30275207#30275207

Comment: @v.ladynev it's not a bad thing to have a Maven application for these purpose ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/BocOperations/src/operations/SV.csv");
```

If you use `getResource()` method of a `ClassLoader` you shouldn't add a leading `/` and you need to specify a path begin from of a root package. So if `SV.csv` resides in the `operations` package (and `operations` in the root package)

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
  .getResource("operations/SV.csv");
```

Please, don't use custom implementations to read `CSV` files

[opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

[Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

An example of using `opencsv`

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
                    new FileReader("c:/xxx.csv"));
// Read all rows at once
List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();
```

**Read a file from an URL**

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

You can consider to specify an encoding of a reading file.

Comment: whene i use 
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("operations/SV.csv");

File file = new File(url.getPath());
How can i read the file ?

Comment: @khadi8 You need to open stream from `URL`.

Comment: it's work with new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
thank you

Comment: @khadi8 You are welcome. Don't forget to specify a file encoding :)