# how to get the string returned from a call to exec which is in a java.io.OutputStream

Tags: clojure

I have this:

```
(import 'java.lang.Runtime)

(defn foo []
    (println (.getOutputStream (. (Runtime/getRuntime) exec "pwd"))))
```

It successfully returns a java.io.OutputStream (java docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html

How do I now write this stream using clojure/java interop? I want to get a string of the 'pwd' command.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [slurp](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/slurp). Also you have to use getInputStream instead of getOutputStream method (you want to consume the input stream of the process). This snippet should work :

```
(println (slurp (.getInputStream (.exec (Runtime/getRuntime) "pwd"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the direct answer to the question, but thought it might be helpful to others to mention that https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.shell/sh would be helpful in this situation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best way to get the current working directory.
Take a look here: [Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

Comment: yes indeed, thanks for the link. i was really using pwd as a basic example!