# File Not Found when running on tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, filenotfoundexception

First, I run my method as a `java application` in eclipse and it works fine.

Then, when I run it on the tomcat server, it blows up.

Here is the code:

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(Constants.USERMAP_FILE_LOCATION))))
```

Here is the Exception:

```
com.mycompany.is.dt.Exception.SubversionUtilityException: usermap (No such file or directory)
```

I also tried changing the path. I right clicked on the file in my project and went to properties. It gave me the path `/DevToolsSvn2Git/usermap` but I still got this excetion.

```
com.mycompany.is.dt.Exception.SubversionUtilityException: /DevToolsSvn2Git/usermap (No such file or directory)
```

Is something changing in the WAR that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing the top answer from  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java) to see what folder your application is running in. This will help you figure out where your file/folder reference needs to be to avoid the FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

You must use **AbsolutePath**, which is sth. like

```
"C://User//Project//Git//DevToolsSvn2Git/usermap"
```

Comment: this will not work when i deploy to a different environment

Comment: does your file located in resources??

Comment: `InputStream  input = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);`

Comment: which package are you getting Main from?

Comment: `Main` is Main class, it does not matter where it is located, you may use any class

Comment: it is just sample of how you may get absolute path, the deal is about getting the **AbsolutePath**, there are other ways