# Can't find resources runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl, filenotfoundexception

I can't load an resource file after extracting a project as a runnable jar.

It works in Eclipse but after exporting it throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

I have tried to put the `res` folder next to the `.jar` file but nothing helps. I've tried with JarSplice and got it running with all the libraries but it stops with the resource file. The object file is located in a source folder.

What can I do?

Code

```
    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(new File("res/" + fileName + ".obj"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't load object file!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

EDIT: By opening the runnable .jar file in 7zip I can see that the whole /res folder has disappeared during the exporting and the files in the directory now lies directly in the root folder of the .jar file.

Comment: Try **("./res/" + fileName + ".obj")**

Comment: @MamyKryzysKryzysKryzys Sadly it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the `res` folder should be placed directly off the *present working directory*, which should be the directory where you are running the Java command from. For an example, see this question on [how to determine the current working directory from inside Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java).

Comment: I'll take a look at it and see if things clear out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work. We can dig further if need be. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Path instead of new File(string).

```
FileReader fr = null;
try {
    fr = new FileReader(Paths.get("res/" + fileName + ".obj").toFile());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't load object file!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```