# How to know absolute path to a properties loaded by resourceBoundle

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm loading a properties using below code:

```
ResourceBoundle boundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("file")
```

I want to know the absolute path of the loaded file. For example if I execute this code in a web application in webapps folder of a tomcat I want to obtain:

```
c:\tomcat8\webapps\example\WEB-INF\classes\file.properties.
```

How can I know this path?

Comment: in your above code, file is what? is it object of File class

Comment: I have changed it for "file". file is the filename of the properties

Comment: Wrong way to go. Resources in a webapp are virtual and may not be mapped to physical files if your war file is not expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I have 'resolved' my problem with this post ['Getting current working directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java). For my problem I only need this, once I know the working directory I can find the absolute path

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    URL location = Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    System.out.println(location.getFile());
}}
```

I think that perhaps this solution does not cover all the situations, but it is enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the physical location from a `ResourceBundle`, but if you know the path that was used to load it, then you can find out the physical location of *that*. Like this:

```
String resourceToLoad = "file";
URL url = this.getClassLoader().getResource(resourceToLoad);
ResourceBoundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(resourceToLoad);
```

The `url` will have the physical location of the resource -- at least most of the time.

Remember that a `ResourceBundle` can also be backed by a Java class rather than something like a properties file. `ClassLoader.getResource` doesn't understand the mapping between `ResourceBundle` and Java classes. If you want to be able to support those, you'll have to implement a similar algorithm to what `ResourceBundle` does in order to search for classes that match it's scheme.