# How to make relative path for JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, relative-path

I want to make relative path for my jasper reports but unsuccessful:

```
String REPORT="C:\\Users\\Muhammad Awais\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BILLING\\src\\billing\\MyReports\\report.jrxml";
String rel="BILLING\\src\\billing\\MyReports\\report.jrxml";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the fact that `current working directory` is represented by `.` operator. In relative path, everything else is relative to it. Similar to

```
String relativePath=".\\BILLING\\src\\billing\\MyReports\\report.jrxml";
```

You can refer to the Java Path operations documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html). You can also use `toRealPath()` to get the absolute path of a relative path.

> The toRealPath method returns the real path of an existing file. This method performs several operations in one:
>
> - If true is passed to this method and the file system supports symbolic links, this method resolves any symbolic links in the path.
> - If the Path is relative, it returns an absolute path.
> - If the Path contains any redundant elements, it returns a path with those elements removed.

Comment: Have you tried using `toRealPath()`?

Comment: (the system cannot find  the path secified)

Comment: I guess you might have problem with _Current Working Directory_. Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7603444/6513921).