# File is found when using NetBeans, not found using the terminal

Tags: java, netbeans, filereader, filenotfoundexception

So I have to run a program using the terminal. But when I do that it tells me that the file I'm trying to use can not be found. When I use NetBeans to run my program, there is not problem what so ever.
This id my Code

```
    File file = new File("src/level/Level2.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
```

When it works, the program should open a window with the level from the file.
When trying out "level/Level2.txt" for the filename, it opens an empty window.
Hope anybody can help me.

**EDIT**
I found what was wrong. My Program couldn't find the Images I wanted to display.

Comment: Your user's directory has changed, and this is not surprising. Don't use Files for this, use resources. Google this.

Comment: I tried doing that but it still doesn't work

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense. Your question talks about problems reading a text file. Please fix your question so that we can understand what is going on (or delete it).

Answer (score -1):

To make things less mysterious, you can try using an absolute path instead of relative.

```
String currentDir = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
System.out.println("currentDir = " + currentDir);
```

For example, on my system this output this directory name:

```
currentDir = /Users/harry/Projects/proj3
```

The absolute path to the directory you see from the command line will depen on where you started Java to run from the console.(Assuming your Java app doesn't try to change the current working directory.)

Suggestion borrowed from here:

[Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

I'm suggesting this to help with your particular problem, and **not** as general advice for using paths in Java applications. Relative paths are better... so good to figure out how your program is accessing directories when you run it without your IDE.

Comment: Okay I tried it and it's not the same directory. The terminal gives me:  currentDir = /Users/Henrike/NetBeansProjects/DisCaptive/src                  and netbeans gives me: currentDir = /Users/Henrike/NetBeansProjects/DisCaptive

Comment: Thank you for showing me this. It helped me to get the Images to be found.

Comment: Glad that helped... I should have said that running from the command prompt will give you an answer that depends on where you run the Java command to start your program.

Comment: You should avoid using absolute path unless you want your program running on one and only one computer. Much better to understand and fix the problem.