# IntelliJ IDEA, pack and load image file within an artifact

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea

My application uses some image files. I added them manually to the artifact under File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Output Layout. If I build the artifact and open it with an archive manager I can see that the image files are there under the root path.

How can I load them in the Java code? I have tried both the simple path (like "image.png") and getClass().getResource(), as well as moving the files under  different locations but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Using the full absolute path should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
1) Use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the current user dir, it could be your project root path or some system path. Then you can put files there (see [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java))

2) Use Classloader `ClassLoader.getResource(String name)`. Because of parent delegation model, JVM first look the file up in the classpath of the parent classloader. If you use IDEA, the simplest way is to create a new project using maven. A `resources` folder will be created under `main` folder.
[image]

Comment: There is no resources directory, I tried to create and add it under some different paths but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the resources (the 'image' folder) in the **same package** (in my case 'gui') of the classes that use them, then invoke getClass().getResource("images/icon.png").