# System.getProperty("user.dir") display Eclipse working directory instead my project

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to use my project dir to run the code when I wrote following command,

```
public static String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

its returns me my Eclipse Dir path instead of my workspace path. I tried almost all the ways from here, but couldn't manage to solve the problem.
I also tried

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + s);
```

but it also display same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

Comment: Tried that way result was same as user.dir, isnt solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Open 'Run > Run Configuratons...'.

Find your program in the 'Java Application' section.

On the 'Arguments' tab look at the 'Working directory' section and change this to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It points to the dir where Java starts from. You are starting your app from Eclipse so it shows Eclipse dir. Try to export jar and run by `java -jar my.jar`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run via Eclipse previously, it was successfully run later I deploy the code in Mercurial and then this error comes up.