# Cant retrieve file using relative path

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

I've been scouring the web for a solution to this seemingly simple problem, but I always run into `FileNotFoundException`. I am using Java 8 on Eclipse Oxygen and can't retrieve my `txt` file from either absolute path or relative path. As suggested in other [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java) I got the path to the current directory, which I suppose is where the txt file is loaded from:

`Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("").toAbsolutePath();`

This showed my directory as `E:\eclipse-java-oxygen-R-win32\HashMap`

However, when I added my txt file to that project directory (containing `src`,`bin` directories) it still couldn't find the file when I wrote: `Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("free.txt"))`

I even tried the absolute path: `Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("E://eclipse-java-oxygen-R-win32//HashMap//free.txt"));`

I included a screenshot of the location of my free.txt file below.

[image]Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your path separator might be the issue. Have you tried with / or \\. There is also a pathSeparator constant you could use or the Path API to get rid of the necessity of a path separator

Comment: I've tried with both, but no luck

Comment: What exact message is returned by the OS?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException`

Comment: @st4rgut You're having compile issues. Try running a clean and then build again. Seems like you have a checked exception that you aren't catching.

Comment: Pretty much self explanatory. Surround your call with a try catch block and catch filenotfoundexception. You have a compile time problem because java wants you to specify how you would handle the case of an absent file and maybe some more

Comment: ah thanks, works now. i thought my file was in the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, lets try to split things up so that we know what exactly is the problem. You could also try to get a more explicit error message by printing the exact error of the File Exception. Something like this:

```
catch (IOException e) { 
      System.out.println("IOException caught -- "); 
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

But going further. Your line: `Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("free.txt"))`can be split up.

Try this:

```
String file_name="free.txt";
File file_input = new File(file_name);
if (!file_input.exists())
    abort("FileInput: no such source file: " + file_name);
if (!_file_input.isFile())
    abort("FileInput: can't open a directory: " + file_name);
if (!file_input.canRead())
    abort("FileInput: source file is unreadable: " + file_name);
```

Then run

```
try {
    `Scanner input = new Scanner(file_input)`
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

At least this should tell you more about the error and do the debugging for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your file is but I think this is what you're looking for. i have a file named test.json

```
String jsonString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.json").toURI())));
```