# Am I using Scanner and File class correctly?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am creating a Game of Life program that accepts user input patterns, using `java.util.Scanner` and `java.io.File`

The main issue is that I cannot seem to get the program to read the `pattern.txt` file...

I do not see any issue, the `pattern.txt` is in the same folder as the `.java` and `.class` files when I compile them.

Am I using `File` and `Scanner` correctly?

I've tried reordering the `import` statements, changing `try` & `catch` structure, and creating a new `File(//..Path/../pattern.txt)` to directly call the file via the relative path

`1.txt` is the pattern file:

```
20 20
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

`

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    String inputFileName = "1.txt"; // Directly setting relative path

    int [][] initStates = getInitialStates(inputFileName);

    Grid gd = new Grid(initStates);

    gd.display();
    gd.getStats();
    gd.run();
    }

    public static int [][] getInitialStates(String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
    // checks to see if file was created
    //            if (file.exists())
    //                System.out.println("FILE EXISTS");
    //            else
    //                System.out.println("FILENOTFOUDN");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);     // Create scanner to read file
        int[][] states = null;
        int rows = input.nextInt();                   // get rows and cols values from first values of text file
        int cols = input.nextInt();
        // states = new int[rows][cols];           // Create 2d array w/ rows and cols
        states = new int[rows][cols];
    //        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    //            states[i] = new int[cols];
    //        }

        // Read initial states from the input file
        for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < states[0].length; j++) {
                states[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return states;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    //        return states;
}
```

`

Error output is FileNotFoundException printing the stack trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 1.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:639)
at client.getInitialStates(client.java:67)
at client.main(client.java:24)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Grid.<init>(Grid.java:14)
at client.main(client.java:26)
```

I get the NullPointerException because the getInitialStates() method isn't returning the 2d array because it cannot read the file.

Comment: "The main issue is that I cannot seem to get the program to read the pattern.txt file..." — do you get the `FileNotFoundException`, or the inability to read the file is manifested in some other way?

Comment: Yes, it outputs the FileNotFoundException and a stack trace showing that it causes an error at the Scanner statement.

Comment: Then `FileNotFoundException` is the first issue you will need to solve. It would be better to include it in the question front and center. Working with `Scanner` should be secondary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as per comment a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown, it means that the *working directory* of your program (i.e. directory where `java YourMainClassName` is invoked) is different from location of the file you're trying to open by its name.

You can check the working directory:

```
System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

As described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7603444/1083697

Comment: Awesome! That helped, it seems that IntelliJ needs the .txt file to be in the project folder not in the src folder. That's something to take note of I guess.

Now the program runs and doesn't give FileNotFoundException, although it is not printing the grid.. I guess I have more debugging to do.

Comment: @Small_Kitten, also checkout run configuration settings. One of the options is to change working directory.