# Runnable Jar File doesn't load resources

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, embedded-resource

In IntelliJ I can run:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("src/de/therealjan/tools/pictures/pic.png");
```

But in a runnable JAR File that won't work.
I already tried "/pictures/pic.png" but that doesn't work too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Makesure your relative path is correct. This answer to explains show to get current directory which you started the program https://stackoverflow.com/a/7603444/1431184.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add the image in your classpath or a directory in your classpath
and then load your image like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("src/de/therealjan/tools/pictures/pic.png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resource);
```

Comment: I wrote `URL url = getClass().getResource("src/de/therealjan/tools/pictures/pic.png");
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);` and I got an NullPointerException?

Comment: I added another way that you could try. but where did you get the NullPointer? is it no the getClass()? or on the next line?

Comment: second way worked. Can I use this for every file like txt?

Comment: @TheRealJan Try with `de/therealjan/tools/pictures/pic.png`

Comment: I think yes you can. the best way is to try it out :)

Comment: I tried it but evertime I get "file not found?" (But in IntelliJ everthing works)

Comment: I don't know about text files, you could ask another question but I searched a little bit for you and I come up with this: https://coderanch.com/t/499632/java/load-file-jar-file

Comment: I wanna open this file with Desktop.getDesktop().open() and that's working in IntelliJ