# How to have a program print it's location?

Tags: java, file

I have a java program and I want it to be able to print out its location on the computer. For example, if I were to place the program in the Downloads folder, and run it, it would print out the path to the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
.toURI()).getPath();
```

make sure to change the Myclass.class stuff

then `system.out.println(File)`