# How to fix a FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, io

I am trying to read a file from my desktop, but the following code always throws a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
try {
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new FileReader("project.csv"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // The exception is always thrown.
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: "to find the file in my desktop" are you running the program with the desktop as the current working directory?

Comment: how do i check that ?

Comment: Get current directory see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: thanks. it wasnt on desktop now i get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new FileReader("project.csv")` tells the reader to search for the file in the current working directory, which is most likely your user folder. To get files on the desktop, do:

```
new FileReader("/desktop/project.csv")
```

But just to be safe, I would use the absolute path and include the one to the user directory as well:

```
new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/desktop/project.csv")
```