# How to check if a file exists inside a directory in groovy?

Tags: groovy, directory, file-exists

I am trying to check if **abcd.png** exists inside the **flows** folder

```
flows/abcd.png
```

so in groovy I am doing this

```
def file = new File("flows/abcd.png").exists()
```

but it is returning false. When I do **ls** I can see the file exists inside the flows folder as well. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Also I tried with

```
"/flows/abcd.png"
".flows/abcd.png"
"./flows/abcd.png"
```

But it gives false for all the cases

Comment: Debug/print your current working directory inside your groovy script (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/how-to-get-the-current-working-directory-in-java); your code there is correct - most likely you are not running it from where you think you are running it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use fileExists(), to check the existence of the file

`if (fileExists("${workspace}/flows/abcd.png")) { do_something }`