# How do I get the current working directory when using a Spring Boot LaunchScript

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line-interface

No [not this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4871051/206466)

```java
    var cwd = Path.of( "" );
    log.info( "user.dir: {}", Path.of( System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) ) );
    log.info( "cwd: {}", cwd.toAbsolutePath() );
    log.info( "PWD: {}", System.getenv( "PWD" ) );
```

```
❯ ./modules/app/build/libs/brix-0.1.0.jar --logging.level.com.xenoterracide.brix=info java module foo                                      # brix -> ccushing/release !
INFO  - Starting Application using Java 11.0.11 on CarbonX1-8-Manjaro with PID 51641 (/home/xeno/IdeaProjects/brix/modules/app/build/libs/brix-0.1.0.jar started by xeno in /home/xeno/IdeaProjects/brix/modules/app/build/libs) - com.xenoterracide.brix.Application
INFO  - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default - com.xenoterracide.brix.Application
INFO  - Started Application in 0.843 seconds (JVM running for 1.633) - com.xenoterracide.brix.Application
INFO  - user.dir: /home/xeno/IdeaProjects/brix/modules/app/build/libs - com.xenoterracide.brix.configloader.service.ConfigValueProcessor
INFO  - cwd: /home/xeno/IdeaProjects/brix/modules/app/build/libs - com.xenoterracide.brix.configloader.service.ConfigValueProcessor
INFO  - PWD: /home/xeno/IdeaProjects/brix/modules/app/build/libs - com.xenoterracide.brix.configloader.service.ConfigValueProcessor
Overwrite [yN] module/src/test/java/com/xenoterracide/TestApplication.java 
❯ pwd                                                                                                                                      # brix -> ccushing/release !
/home/xeno/IdeaProjects/brix ####!!!!! THIS ONE
```

^ that last one, in a cross platform compatible way.

I'm using a Spring Boot jar launch script.

```
tasks.withType<BootJar> {
  mainClass.set("com.xenoterracide.brix.Application")
  archiveBaseName.set("brix")
  launchScript {
    properties(
      mapOf(
        "spring.config.location" to "classpath:application.properties"
      )
    )
  }
}
```

how can I get the real working directory?

Comment: The real working directory when your application executes is given by the system property `user.dir`, as you have found. Evidently something has changed it before running your codel. Nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t with the default launch script. [It uses the directory that contains the jar file as the working directory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/). This is primarily aimed at applications that are used as services rather than a CLI application and isn’t customisable with the default script.

I’d recommend using Spring Boot’s ability to build a fully-executable jar file with a custom launch script that meets your needs. You can do so with the `script` property:

```
tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    launchScript {
        script = file("src/custom.script")
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/spring-io/bomr/blob/91a916478d46d89ac803b9c37155d0fbba84407d/launch.script) is a script from a CLI application that may provide a useful starting point:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -n "$DEBUG" ]] && set -x

working_directory="$(pwd)"

# Follow symlinks to find the real jar
cd "$(dirname "$0")" || exit 1
[[ -z "$jarfile" ]] && jarfile=$(pwd)/$(basename "$0")
while [[ -L "$jarfile" ]]; do
  jarfile=$(readlink "$jarfile")
  cd "$(dirname "$jarfile")" || exit 1
  jarfile=$(pwd)/$(basename "$jarfile")
done

cd "$working_directory"

# Find Java
if [[ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]] && [[ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]]; then
    javaexe="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
elif type -p java > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    javaexe=$(type -p java)
elif [[ -x "/usr/bin/java" ]];  then
    javaexe="/usr/bin/java"
else
    echo "Unable to find Java"
    exit 1
fi

arguments=(-Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true $JAVA_OPTS -jar "$jarfile" $RUN_ARGS "$@")

"$javaexe" "${arguments[@]}"
exit $?
```

Comment: Seems like a bug that it breaks this... I wouldn't expect any Unix application to work this way, especially since you can't get that information at all. But ok, thanks. Would be good to have the plug-in documentation document example scripts, and or maybe the location of the used script as well as any surprising behavior like this.